# Data from file as list in \foreach in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, external-files

I have data stored in files I named  x.dat and y.dat. In the file are two columns and each row stands for one point. These points I plot in the beginning. But then I want some arrows from the x-points to the y-points. So I need a foreach over the points. But those points are not stored in a way the foreach-statement can handle.

How can I get the foreach-statement to walk through the points in the files, without changing the files?

```
\draw plot [only marks, mark=*, mark options={fill=red, scale=0.3}]
    file {x.dat};
\foreach \x  in file {x.dat}
    \foreach \y in file {y.dat}
    {
        \draw [->] \x -- \y;
    }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a code based on Torbjørn's code but here I try to use `pgfplotstable`. I'm not a great expert of this package also it's perhaps possible to use some useful macro to read `\xA` and `\yA` directly.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable,tikz,filecontents}

\begin{document} 
  \begin{filecontents*}{coord1.dat}
% x   y
0    0
1    1
2    2
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{coord2.dat}
%  x   y
0    1
1    2
2    3
\end{filecontents*}
  \pgfplotstableread{coord1.dat}{\firsttable}   
  \pgfplotstableread{coord2.dat}{\secodtable} 
  \pgfplotstablegetrowsof{coord1.dat}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\rows}{\pgfplotsretval-1}      
\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \i in {0,...,\rows}{%
  \pgfplotstablegetelem{\i}{[index] 0}\of{\firsttable} 
  \let\xA\pgfplotsretval 
  \pgfplotstablegetelem{\i}{[index] 1}\of{\firsttable} 
  \let\yA\pgfplotsretval     
  \foreach \j in {0,...,\rows}{%
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{\j}{[index] 0}\of{\secodtable} 
    \let\xB\pgfplotsretval 
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{\j}{[index] 1}\of{\secodtable} 
    \let\yB\pgfplotsretval        
    \draw [-latex] (\xA,\yA) node[below]{\xA,\yA} -- (\xB,\yB) node[above]{\xB,\yB};
  }%
 }%   
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That worked. Some changes I have made and I had to copy the actual version to my computer. But it worked. :)

Answer (score 8):

### Solution #1 – datatool

Unless I misunderstand, you can use `datatool`, similar to [Drawing different tikz shapes parameterized by data from a file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20496/drawing-different-tikz-shapes-parameterized-by-data-from-a-file/20501#20501).

The files with the coordinates are created by the `filecontents*` environment.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{datatool,tikz,filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{coord1.dat}
x,y
0,0
1,1
2,2
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{coord2.dat}
x,y
0,1
1,2
2,3
\end{filecontents*}
\DTLloaddb[noheader=false]{coordinates1}{coord1.dat}
\DTLloaddb[noheader=false]{coordinates2}{coord2.dat}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\DTLforeach*{coordinates1}{\xA=x, \yA=y}{%
  \DTLforeach*{coordinates2}{\xB=x, \yB=y}{
     \draw [-latex] (\xA,\yA) node[below]{\xA,\yA} -- (\xB,\yB) node[above]{\xB,\yB};}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

### Solution #2 – Lua

The following may be, I don't know, horrible. It uses Lua code to read the files and loop over the coordinates, and must therefore be compiled with `lualatex`. The same files, `coord1.dat` and `coord2.dat` were used, written in the same way. I took the easy way, so you cannot access the separate `x` and `y` coordinates of each point, as each element in the lua tables `Ca` and `Cb` contains one line of the file, *e.g.*, `1,1`. Also, as it is, this won't work if the two coordinate lists are of different lengths.

The output is the same as above.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz,luacode,filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{coord1.dat}
x,y
0,0
1,1
2,2
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{coord2.dat}
x,y
0,1
1,2
2,3
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{luacode}
c1 = io.open("./coord1.dat","r")
c2 = io.open("./coord2.dat","r")
local count = 1
Ca = {}
Cb = {}
while true do
  local line1 = c1:read()
  local line2 = c2:read()
  if line1 == nil then break end
  Ca[count], Cb[count] = line1, line2
  count = count + 1
end
c1:close()
c2:close()
rows = \#Ca
for i=2,rows do
  for j=2,rows do
    tex.sprint("\\draw [-latex] (", Ca[i], ")node[below]{", Ca[i], "} -- (", Cb[j], ") node[above] {", Cb[j], "};")
  end
end
\end{luacode}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Somehow doesn't work for me:

"
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...entryfromcurrentrow {\noexpand  \yA 
                                                  }{\dtl@columnindex {coordi...
l.10 ...,\yA} -- (\xB,\yB) node[above]{\xB,\yB};}}
                                                  
? 
"

Comment: @pirad Sorry, don't know what's wrong. Old version of `datatool` perhaps? (See [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13305/586) for how to check the version, I have v2.03 from 2009/11/15.)