# Number of rows in loaded table

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

Is it possible to determine the number of rows in a table read by `pgfplotstableread{values.dat}\val`  ?

My setup is the following. I make experiments to see how a parameter affects a convergence curve. Results of such experiments look like

```
[results.dat]
n err_0 err_1 err_2 err_3
1024 0.1 0.2 0.15
2084 0.01 0.02 0.015
4096 0.001 0.002 0.0015
```

Parameters for each experiment is saved in a second table

```
[meta.dat]
0.5
2
3.7
11
```

Now I want to plot the results automatically (without knowing the number of experiments or the parameters)

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread{results.dat}\values
\pgfplotstableread{meta.dat}\meta
\def\N{3} %change to automatic here

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{loglogaxis}
\foreach \i in {0,...,\N}{
%use elements from meta table here instead of \i
\edef\theLegend{\noexpand\addlegendentry{Generalized \i}}
\addplot table[x=n,y=err_\i]{\values};
\theLegend
}   
\end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The two points I have trouble with are marked with comments.

Comment: During `\pgfplotstabletypeset` you can access it via `\pgfplotstablerows`

Comment: Can I use that without typesetting it at all? I use it for plots.

Comment: Can you make an example how you want to use it? for plots you also have `\coordindex` in `pgfplots`

Comment: I added the shortest example I could think of.

Comment: Two things ; `\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{<file name or loadedtable>}` gives the number in your original question or you can loop over columns with `\pgfplotstableforeachcolumn<table>`. You can check which one is your case in the manual

Answer (score 3):

Using the pointers of percusse and the answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36472/5737 I came to the following solution for my problem.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread{results.dat}\values
\pgfplotstableread{meta.dat}\meta
%number of experiments
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\meta}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\N}{\pgfplotsretval-1}  

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{loglogaxis}
\foreach \i in {0,...,\N}{
%get parameter
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\i}{[index]0}\of{\meta} 
\let\param\pgfplotsretval
\edef\theLegend{\noexpand\addlegendentry{Generalized \param}}
\addplot table[x=n,y=err_\i]{\values};
\theLegend
}   
\end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```