# Parametrize shading in table through TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, color, conditionals

I wanted to do some shading in a table according to its values. For example, if you see the table below:

```
  a  b   c   d 
a 90 10  0   0
b 0  80  10  10
c 0  0   95  5
d 0  10  5   85
```

I want to shade automatically each numeric cell with a mixture of black and white according to its value. That is, `(a,a) = 90` should be something like `black!90`, and `(c,d) = 5` should be `black!5`. Also, if you can parametrized the shading operation so one can define the color and if we use the value or the complement that would be great.

I was thinking in something like [Drawing different tikz shapes parameterized by data from a file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20496/drawing-different-tikz-shapes-parameterized-by-data-from-a-file), but I cannot see how can one achieve that in a table.

Can you give me some advice on how to achieve such automatic styling?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You could use pgfplotstable and the `xcolor` package with the `[table]` option, which gives you the `\cellcolor` command.

Here's a new style for `\pgfplotstabletypeset` that colors the cell a different shade of gray according to the cell value, and prints the value in white if the background is more than 50% black.

The command

```
\pgfplotstabletypeset[color cells]{
 x,a,b,c,d      % The first column needs a name
 a,90,10,0,0
 b,0,80,10,10
 c,0,0,95,5
 d,0,10,5,85
 }
```

will then give you (shown here with a caption)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotstableset{
    color cells/.style={
        col sep=comma,
        string type,
        postproc cell content/.code={%
                \pgfkeysalso{@cell content=\rule{0cm}{2.4ex}\cellcolor{black!##1}\pgfmathtruncatemacro\number{##1}\ifnum\number>50\color{white}\fi##1}%
                },
        columns/x/.style={
            column name={},
            postproc cell content/.code={}
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}\caption{Correlation or something}
\centering
\pgfplotstabletypeset[color cells]{
x,a,b,c,d
a,90,10.5,0,0
b,0,80,10,10
c,0,0,95,5
d,0,10,5,85
}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks it works really nice. That was what I was expecting. However, when I put the `\pgfplotstabletypeset` inside a table environment (`\begin{table} ... \end{table}`) I get a `Not in outer par mode` error. So, is there any option to put that table in an environment? so I can add a caption to it, and style as other tables in my document?

Comment: That error occurs only if you're using the `standalone` class. In "normal" classes, you should be able to use the `table` environment. I've edited my example.

Comment: Thanks, I feel so dumb. I didn't check that part. Now is working. By the way, is it me, or the numbers are not aligned in the middle of the rows? or is just a visual effect due to the shading?

Comment: Don't worry, I was quite surprised that it didn't work in `standalone`, too. The numbers look like they're too far up because there's space left for the descender of letters like `g`, `j`, or `q`. If you add `\rule{0cm}{2.4ex}` before `\cellcolor`, they'll loke more centered.

Comment: btw, how do you transform the numbers into integers, so the style also works for decimal numbers? I try to replace the `##1` by `\pgftruncatemacro##1`, `\pgftruncatemacro{##1}`, `\pgfmathparse{round(##1)}`; but none of those work. I'm not very familiar with pgf, sorry for being this pushing.

Comment: `\pgfmathtruncatemacro\somemacroname{##1}`. You need to save the result into a macro, the command doesn't change the content of `##1` itself.

Comment: how do i change the code for values between 0 and 1?

Answer (score 15):

I wanted to retain the use of tabular, so I used a macro to format the cells. Definitely longer but more familiar to me.

```
\def\cca#1{\cellcolor{black!#10}\ifnum #1>5\color{white}\fi{#1}}
%For ranges 0-10, multiply by 10 by adding 0 after #1

\begin{table}[!t]
\caption{Table Caption}
\label{tab1}
\centering
{\setlength\tabcolsep{0.1pt}%
\begin{tabular}{ccccccccccccccc}
& $D_1$ & $D_2$ & $D_3$ & $D_4$ & $D_5$ & $D_6$ && & $D_1$ & $D_2$ & $D_3$ & $D_4$ & $D_5$ & $D_6$ \\
$D_1$ & & \cca{0} & \cca{0} & \cca{0} & \cca{2} & \cca{0} && $D_1$ && \cca{0} & \cca{0} & \cca{2} & \cca{2} & \cca{2} \\
$D_2$ & \cca{0} & & \cca{2} & \cca{0} & \cca{2} & \cca{0} && $D_2$ & \cca{0} &  & \cca{3} & \cca{0} & \cca{0} & \cca{2} \\
$D_3$ & \cca{7} & \cca{4} &  & \cca{3} & \cca{0} & \cca{4} && $D_3$ & \cca{0} & \cca{4} &  & \cca{4} & \cca{2} & \cca{0} \\
$D_4$ & \cca{3} & \cca{0} & \cca{7} &  & \cca{4} & \cca{0} && $D_4$ & \cca{0} & \cca{0} & \cca{5} &  & \cca{0} & \cca{0} \\
$D_5$ & \cca{3} & \cca{7} & \cca{7} & \cca{2} &  & \cca{4} && $D_5$ & \cca{2} & \cca{2} & \cca{0} & \cca{4} &  & \cca{4} \\
$D_6$ & \cca{2} & \cca{2} & \cca{7} & \cca{2} & \cca{6} &  && $D_6$ & \cca{2} & \cca{2} & \cca{3} & \cca{0} & \cca{4} & \\
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}
```

[image: table result]

Comment: this looks like exactly what I need. But I get errors when I try to change the range. If I wanted something like 0-230, how would I amend your `\def`? Hope you can help :)

Comment: Please embed you solution into a MWE that is actually compilable.

Comment: @JTIM see this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/281828/26887

Comment: @DanielHershcovich Cool to give such a comment, I ended up solving it in a different way back then :) But THX!

Answer (score 8):

If you want that the cell background color changes according to its values.

[image: Correlation or other kind of matrix]

You can use the following code.

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{collcell}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{multirow}

\def\colorModel{hsb} %You can use rgb or hsb

\newcommand\ColCell[1]{
  \pgfmathparse{#1<50?1:0}  %Threshold for changing the font color into the cells
    \ifnum\pgfmathresult=0\relax\color{white}\fi
  \pgfmathsetmacro\compA{0}      %Component R or H
  \pgfmathsetmacro\compB{#1/100} %Component G or S
  \pgfmathsetmacro\compC{1}      %Component B or B
  \edef\x{\noexpand\centering\noexpand\cellcolor[\colorModel]{\compA,\compB,\compC}}\x #1
  } 
\newcolumntype{E}{>{\collectcell\ColCell}m{0.4cm}<{\endcollectcell}}  %Cell width

\begin{document}
\newcommand\items{3}   %Number of classes
\arrayrulecolor{white} %Table line colors
\noindent\begin{tabular}{c*{\items}{|E}|}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{A} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{B} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{C} \\ \hhline{~*\items{|-}|}
A  & 100   & 0  & 10   \\ \hhline{~*\items{|-}|}
B  & 10   & 80  & 10   \\ \hhline{~*\items{|-}|}
C  & 30   & 0   & 70   \\ \hhline{~*\items{|-}|}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

You can use RGB or HSB to define your color ranges, and you can control de color ranges using the formulas in compA, compB and compC.

So, for "Autum" (red-yellow) range use:

```
\pgfmathsetmacro\compA{#1/600} %Component R or H
\pgfmathsetmacro\compB{1} %Component G or S
\pgfmathsetmacro\compC{1} %Component B or B
```

And, for "Cool" (cyan-magenta) range set rgb for color model and use:

```
\pgfmathsetmacro\compA{#1/100}   %Component R or H
\pgfmathsetmacro\compB{1-#1/100} %Component G or S
\pgfmathsetmacro\compC{1}        %Component B or B
```

For "Black-red" range use:

```
\pgfmathsetmacro\compA{0} %Component R or H
\pgfmathsetmacro\compB{1} %Component G or S
\pgfmathsetmacro\compC{#1/100} %Component B or B
```

For "Jet" range use:

```
\pgfmathsetmacro\compA{0.6666-#1/150}      %Component R or H
\pgfmathsetmacro\compB{1} %Component G or S
\pgfmathsetmacro\compC{1}      %Component B or B
```

For "Cooper" range use:

```
\pgfmathsetmacro\compA{0.08+#1/5000}      %Component R or H
\pgfmathsetmacro\compB{0.7} %Component G or S
\pgfmathsetmacro\compC{#1/100}      %Component B or B
```

For "Gray" range use:

```
\pgfmathsetmacro\compA{0}      %Component R or H
\pgfmathsetmacro\compB{0} %Component G or S
\pgfmathsetmacro\compC{#1/100}      %Component B or B
```

[image]

Comment: it is throwing an error with decimal number. my range is from 0.0 to 1 and threshold is 0.50. How can it be done then?

Answer (score 2):

```
\definecolor{myFlowTableTextCol}{rgb}{0,0,0}
\definecolor{myFlowTableBgCol}{rgb}{1.0,0.5,0.0}

% Heatmap style
\pgfkeys{
/pgfplots/table/heatmap/.style =
{
header=false,
column type={p{0.4cm}},
display columns/0/.style={column name=$\phantom{x}$},
display columns/1/.style={column name=$\phantom{x}$},
display columns/2/.style={column name=$\phantom{x}$},
display columns/3/.style={column name=$\phantom{x}$},
display columns/4/.style={column name=$\phantom{x}$},
display columns/5/.style={column name=$\phantom{x}$},
display columns/6/.style={column name=$\phantom{x}$},
display columns/7/.style={column name=$\phantom{x}$},
display columns/8/.style={column name=$\phantom{x}$},
display columns/9/.style={column name=$\phantom{x}$},
display columns/10/.style={column name=$\phantom{x}$},
postproc cell content/.code=
{%
\pgfkeysalso{/pgfplots/table/@cell content=\pgfmathparse{#1} \edef\multFact{\pgfmathresult} \pgfmathparse{round(##1*\multFact)} \edef\x{\pgfmathresult} \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\y}{\x}

\rule{0cm}{2.4ex}%\y,\y,\y}
\ifnum\y<0 \color{lightgray}\cellcolor{lightgray}\fi
\ifnum\y>0 \ifnum\y <6 \color{myFlowTableTextCol}\cellcolor{myFlowTableBgCol!36}\fi\fi
...
\y
},
},
/pgfplots/table/heatmap/.default=100
}

...
\pgfplotstabletypeset[heatmap=162]{data.dat}
```

even allows you to preprocess (multiply in this case) the data before colouring the heatmap. Especially for pgf versions < 1.5 this can be hard otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

I used @Unas answer with the following twist for a custom range, 93.6 to 97.2 in this case:

```
\def\cca#1{%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\calc{(#1-93.6)*100/(97.2-93.6)}%
    \edef\clrmacro{\noexpand\cellcolor{blue!\calc}}%
    \clrmacro%
    \ifdim \calc pt>50pt\color{white}\fi{#1}%
}
```

The reason for the `\edef` instead of simply having `\cellcolor{blue!\calc}` is that otherwise the `\calc` part does not expand.

Also note the `%` at the end of each line. This prevents spaces from appearing in the cells