# Drawing heatmaps using TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfplotstable

**Introduction**

I want to create a heatmap using TikZ.
You can see the basic idea in the picture below:
I basically have a table of values and each value is assigned a color.
The picture is the result of the [R package ggplot2](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/), which however has some limitations.
Thus it was my idea to do the heat maps in LaTeX/TikZ.

Sorry if this gets lengthy but I want to describe unambiguously what I want to do.

**What I want to plot**

1. I want to plot a table.
2. Each cell should have the same size and a value inside it. The values are signed integers. The raw values are printed centered in the cell. Additionally, I want to give the cells a background color, which basically is `blue!{value * -0.05}` for negative values and `red!{value * 0.05}` for positive values.
3. For the colors, I want replace all negative values < -200 by -200, all positive values > 200 by 200.
4. I want to have a horizontal and a vertical axis with labels.

I will probably generate LaTeX and TikZ code using a preprocessing script.
However, I hoped that I could plot the cells with macros to make the result more compact.

**How far I got on my own**

I have done 1-3 on my own - more or less elegantly.
My problem is now how to draw the axes in a nice way.

**My questions**

- Can I improve the current code for 1-3?
- How can I draw the axes elegantly and without having to specify manual coordinates?

**Example Data**

As requested, here is some example data.

The full data looks as follows.
I imported this data into R and then filtered by the values of the dummycol{1,2,3}.
I could generate one data file per heat map, however, without problems.

```
dummycol1 dummycolo2 rowlabel dummycol3 valuecol1 valuecol2 valuecol3 valuecol4
.         .          100      .         -86       -81       -124      -138
.         .          99       .         -90       -96       -122      -108
.         .          98       .         -91       -105      -92       -55
```

**Code**

Here is my current code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning}

\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcommand{\trimmed}{foo}
\newcommand{\bgcolor}{foo}
\newcommand{\hmValue}{0}
\newcommand{\transparency}{0}
\newcommand{\hmColor}{}

\newcommand{\HeatmapNode}[1]{
  \ifthenelse{#1 < -200}
  {
    \renewcommand{\trimmed}{-200}
  }
  % else
  {
    \ifthenelse{#1 > 200}
    {
      \renewcommand{\trimmed}{200}
    }
    % else
    {
      \renewcommand{\trimmed}{#1}
    }
  }

  \ifthenelse{#1 < 0}
  {
    \pgfmathparse{round(\trimmed * -0.5)}
    \node [fill=red!\pgfmathresult] {#1};
  }
  % else
  {
    \pgfmathparse{round(\trimmed * 0.5)}
    \node [fill=blue!\pgfmathresult] {#1};
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix(A) [nodes={rectangle,minimum width=2cm,minimum height=1cm}]
  {
    \node {0}; & \HeatmapNode{-300} & \HeatmapNode{-200} & \HeatmapNode{-100} \\
    \node {1}; & \HeatmapNode{0} & \HeatmapNode{100} & \HeatmapNode{200} \\
    \node {2}; & \HeatmapNode{300} & \HeatmapNode{40} & \HeatmapNode{800} \\
    \node {};  & \node{30}; & \node{50}; & \node{70}; \\
  };

\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Example of a heat map.]

**EDIT** Adding example data.

Comment: Can you give us some dummy data to demonstrate what format it's going to be in?

Comment: Also, this could be of interest: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42444/parametrize-shading-in-table-through-tikz

Comment: `\newcommand{\HeatmapNode}[1]{\pgfmathparse{round(min(abs(#1),200) * 0.5)}\node [fill=\ifnum#1>0 blue\else red\fi!\pgfmathresult] {#1};}`

Comment: @Jake: Added data. However, the related question looks **very** related, I'll have a look there.

Comment: You can use ggplot2 with [tikzDevice](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tikzDevice/index.html).

Comment: Did you get anywhere using the question that Jake linked to?  If so, we could close this as a duplicate of the other one to better help others looking for similar solutions.  If not, please edit your question to explain what went wrong when you tried that solution.

Answer (score 37):

Here is a solution which maps the numerical data linearly into a `colormap` of `pgfplots`.

A `colormap` is a map where the smallest number is mapped to the first color and the largest number is mapped to the last color. Anything in-between is interpolated linearly, i.e. a number which is in the middle between the smallest and the largest will be mapped to a color "in the middle of the colormap". Note that a colormap can be defined by means of any number of colors, not just two. In that case, the intervals will be glued together (compare pgfplots manual).

This allows continous colors as in your screenshot.

*EDIT*: added support to change the text color based on the cell color and improved integration into non-string-type column types.

*EDIT*: in order to keep this a reference, I incorporated bugfixes/improvements from the follow-up question [Heatmap of a triangular matrix (or a sparse matrix)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96403/heatmap-of-a-triangular-matrix-or-a-sparse-matrix)

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotstableset{
    /color cells/min/.initial=0,
    /color cells/max/.initial=1000,
    /color cells/textcolor/.initial=,
    %
    % Usage: 'color cells={min=<value which is mapped to lowest color>, 
    %   max = <value which is mapped to largest>}
    color cells/.code={%
        \pgfqkeys{/color cells}{#1}%
        \pgfkeysalso{%
            postproc cell content/.code={%
                %
                \begingroup
                %
                % acquire the value before any number printer changed
                % it:
                \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@preprocessed cell content}\value
                \ifx\value\empty
                    \endgroup
                \else
                \pgfmathfloatparsenumber{\value}%
                \pgfmathfloattofixed{\pgfmathresult}%
                \let\value=\pgfmathresult
                %
                % map that value:
                \pgfplotscolormapaccess
                    [\pgfkeysvalueof{/color cells/min}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/color cells/max}]
                    {\value}
                    {\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/colormap name}}%
                % now, \pgfmathresult contains {<R>,<G>,<B>}
                % 
                % acquire the value AFTER any preprocessor or
                % typesetter (like number printer) worked on it:
                \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}\typesetvalue
                \pgfkeysgetvalue{/color cells/textcolor}\textcolorvalue
                %
                % tex-expansion control
                % see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12668/where-do-i-start-latex-programming/27589#27589
                \toks0=\expandafter{\typesetvalue}%
                \xdef\temp{%
                    \noexpand\pgfkeysalso{%
                        @cell content={%
                            \noexpand\cellcolor[rgb]{\pgfmathresult}%
                            \noexpand\definecolor{mapped color}{rgb}{\pgfmathresult}%
                            \ifx\textcolorvalue\empty
                            \else
                                \noexpand\color{\textcolorvalue}%
                            \fi
                            \the\toks0 %
                        }%
                    }%
                }%
                \endgroup
                \temp
                \fi
            }%
        }%
    }
}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    color cells={min=-300,max=800},
    col sep=comma,
]{
    a,b,c,d
    50,-300,-200,-100
    -20,0,100,200
    5,300,40,800
    3,30,50,70
}
%
%
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    color cells={min=-300,max=800},
    col sep=comma,
    /pgfplots/colormap={whiteblue}{rgb255(0cm)=(255,255,255); rgb255(1cm)=(0,0,188)},
]{
    a,b,c,d
    50,-300,-200,-100
    -20,0,100,200
    5,300,40,800
    3,30,50,70
}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    color cells={min=0,max=0.8,textcolor=-mapped color!80!black},
    /pgfplots/colormap/greenyellow,
    /pgf/number format/sci,
]{
    a   b   c   d
    5e-1    8e-1    4.4e-2  1e-3     
    0.050   -0.300  -0.200  -0.100
    -0.20   0.1 0.100   0.200
    0.005   0.300   0.40    0.800
    0.8 0.030   0.050   0.70
}
\end{document}
```

The style here assumes that you set the minimum and maximum value manually. If a number is below or above the minimum/maximum, it will be clipped automatically.

After my first *edit*, the style respects any output format instructions, i.e. you can apply number formatting and/or postprocessing as with any other data in `pgfplotstable`. It also makes the code a little bit more complex.

The last entry shows that data in the range [0,1] also seems to work reasonably... and it also shows that the text (foreground) color can be changed in dependence on `mapped color`.

My document shows two different colormaps for the same data. You may want to study the pgfplots manual to learn how to customize `colormap`s.

Comment: This really looks like the ultimate heatmap code! :) I'm having trouble with my floating point matrix though whose values are in [0, 1]. Do real numbers work for you? Also, can you explain to the noob that I am why you chose not to predefine `col sep` and `string type`?

Comment: @Christian Since I like pretty pictures (especially if they appear to be useful), I added improved support for `string type` and standard number formatting. This allows to leave `string type` away entirely. The `col sep` should not be predefined as part of the `color cells` style - what if you have a different separator as in my third example (see edit)?

Comment: Hey great, thanks! But what I meant: wouldn't something like `/color cells/col sep/.initial=comma` work?

Comment: Default value doesn't seem to work. But I really don't understand this syntax anyway. I also tried to improve the non-decimal handling myself with `\IfDecimal` so you could have strings in the first column say. I totally failed :/

Comment: @Christian you can simply say `col sep=comma` somewhere in order to define a default, there is nothing wrong with it! I just did not want to define it as part of the `color cells` style. The prefix `/color cells/` is unsuitable with `col sep` because `col sep` is predefined with a different prefix. Concerning the non-decimal handling etc: please refer to the pgfplotstable manual for how to define column-specific styles. The `\IfDecimal` might work, but only if it has been provided in the correct context.

Comment: @Christian sorry for not reading your initial comment to my answer properly - I have edited my answer such that it accepts floating point numbers as input.

Comment: Thanks for all the work you put into this. I'm going to give you a bounty as a small token of my recognition. In the meanwhile I found out how to get non-number columns ignored. For the record, so other people don't have to try to understand the horribly complex pgfplotstable manual: for every column you have to reset the style which is done using the first row of that column. If say the first cell contains "x", then put this in the [] along with `col sep=comma` and all the rest: `columns/x/.style={reset styles,string type}`.

Comment: The best-practise would be to use `columns/a/.style={color cells={...}}, ...` i.e. to white-list all columns for which you'd like to enable a specific style. However, your approach is correct (you have created a "black list" for which the style is not applicable").

Comment: I was afraid so ;) This best practice is quite tedious for larger matrices but it's good to know that you can do both and that I didn't miss anything with my approach.

Comment: Makes sense. Perhaps I should document the `reset styles` stuff in a better way (i.e. to document how to black-list stuff)

Comment: Just wanted to link to a follow-up question I posted: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96403/heatmap-of-triangular-matrix-or-a-sparse-matrix

Comment: @Christian Now that I stumbled over this post again, I realized that there was a further spurious white space in the pgfplots code. I have fixed that and I removed at the spurious space found by David Carlisle in your link. My answer here reflects that now.

Comment: Just to be sure I understand: did you find *another* spurious space? Because in the edit I can only see the one from David.

Comment: @Christian Yes, I found another one in the code base of pgfplots. It was never visible until this post because pgfplots uses colormaps only within tikzpictures (where `\nullfont` is active). It will be removed in the next pgfplots version.

Comment: Ah ok, now I get it. Great, I'm looking forward to the next pgfplots version then :)

Comment: Is there a simple way to modify this code to not color the first column of the table? (as these are commonly labels of some kind)

Comment: @PatrickSanan it should be possible to move `color cells` into the styles for all other columns except for the first, yes. Maybe you should ask this as separate question

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/268764/heatmap-style-table-coloring-a-subset-of-rows-and-columns

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger  I have a similar question about using `pgfplotstable` package in a little more complex situation (multiple CSV files with data, not only one). If you're interested, you can have a look at it [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/350393/pggfplotstable-input-data-from-multiple-csv-files). I'd really appreciate it :-)

Answer (score 21):

I made this little example by following the result of the [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42444/parametrize-shading-in-table-through-tikz), but it wasn't straightforward to change it, as I encounter this [other problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54872/undefined-control-sequence-error-when-defining-a-color-through-a-macro/54887#54887) (btw, thank you to Andrew Stacy for his help finding what was wrong).

Any way, I think this code achieves what you are trying to do. In summary, the code rounds up the number in the cell by a factor of 0.5. However, as [Andrew noticed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54887/7561), you need to put some safeguards to prevent the color going out of range ([0,100]). And then you need to circunvent the expansion problem. Thus, the `\edef` and the `\temp` macros. Also, I added the white color if the value is above 50, you can tweak it or remove it as you wish.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotstableset{
    color cells/.style={
        col sep=comma,
        string type,
        postproc cell content/.code={%
                \pgfkeysalso{@cell content=\rule{0cm}{2.4ex}%
                \pgfmathsetmacro\y{min(100,max(0,abs(round(##1 * 0.5))))}%
                \ifnum##1<0\edef\temp{\noexpand\cellcolor{blue!\y}}\temp\fi%
                \ifnum##1>0\edef\temp{\noexpand\cellcolor{red!\y}}\temp\fi%
                \pgfmathtruncatemacro\x\y%
                \ifnum\x>50 \color{white}\fi%
                ##1}%
                }
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}\caption{Correlation or something}
\centering
\pgfplotstabletypeset[color cells]{
a,b,c,d
50,-300,-200,-100
-20,0,100,200
5,300,40,800
3,30,50,70
}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: heatmap]

Answer (score 12):

If you're not too familiar with `\pgfplotstableset` and it's somewhat cryptic looking syntax (to me at least) a more readable alternative is to use simple TiKZ nodes with `\foreach` loops running over a list of lists:

[image: heatmap]

```tex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]
  \foreach \y [count=\n] in {
      {74,25,39,20,3,3,3,3,3},
      {25,53,31,17,7,7,2,3,2},
      {39,31,37,24,3,3,3,3,3},
      {20,17,24,37,2,2,6,5,5},
      {3,7,3,2,12,1,0,0,0},
      {3,7,3,2,1,36,0,0,0},
      {3,2,3,6,0,0,45,1,1},
      {3,3,3,5,0,0,1,23,1},
      {3,2,3,5,0,0,1,1,78},
    } {
      % column labels
      \ifnum\n<10
        \node[minimum size=6mm] at (\n, 0) {\n};
      \fi
      % heatmap tiles
      \foreach \x [count=\m] in \y {
        \node[fill=yellow!\x!purple, minimum size=6mm, text=white] at (\m,-\n) {\x};
      }
    }

  % row labels
  \foreach \a [count=\i] in {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i} {
    \node[minimum size=6mm] at (0,-\i) {\a};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How would you add column labels here?

Comment: @Sterling See my updated answer.

Comment: Hey Casimir, this super helpful! A quick question: how would I want the color to make gradually become red from white - yellow - red in ascending order from 0 to say 10?

Comment: @FrankSwanton You could try the `xcolor` RGB mixing syntax which TikZ supports: `fill={rgb:red,1;green,2;blue,5}` and replace the numbers with functions of `\x`. If that doesn't work, I think you'll have to use `pgfplot` functionality. Maybe [this helps](https://pgfplots.net/color-maps).