# 'Undefined control sequence' error when defining a color through a macro

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, expansion

I'm trying to color a cell using its data value. However, when I try to compute some value (using the content of the cell) then the definition of the color `color!\somemacro` in the `\cellcolor` does not work. Where the `\somemacro` stores the result of the computation.

The error I got is:

> ! Undefined control sequence. 
>    blue!\y

Why is this happening? I guess that the problem has to do with the expansion part of the macros, but I don't know how this works. Can someone also explain how/why this happens and how to avoid it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotstableset{
    color cells/.style={
        col sep=comma,
        string type,
        postproc cell content/.code={%
                \pgfkeysalso{@cell content=\rule{0cm}{2.4ex}%
                \pgfmathsetmacro\y{round(##1 * 0.5)}\cellcolor{blue!\y}%
                ##1}%
                }
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}\caption{Colors}
\centering
\pgfplotstabletypeset[color cells]{
a,b,c,d
50,300,200,100
20,0,100,200
}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The command `\cellcolor` doesn't actually set the cell colour there and then, it squirrels it away for later processing.  Although my style-file parsing skills were not up to figuring out exactly where it is finally used, a clue as to why your code breaks is that the squirrelling process defines a *global* macro `\CT@cell@color`.  As it is global, I suspect it will get processed outside the current group.  This global macro saves the colour definition *as-is*: putting `\show\CT@cell@color` after the `\cellcolor` declaration (with suitable `\makeatletter ... \makeatother`) we get the following in the log file:

```
\CT@cell@color=macro:
->\CT@color {blue!\y }\global \let \CT@cell@color \relax .
```

So the `\CT@cell@color` macro saves its argument with the `\y` intact.  But (probably) processes it outside the group in which `\y` has been set.  One might try to make `\y` global, but I found that that caused problems.  The other usual way to avoid these issues is to force `\y` to be expanded before it is passed to `\cellcolor`.  The simplest way to do that is with an `\edef` and a temporary macro.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/54872/86}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}


\pgfplotstableset{
    color cells/.style={
        col sep=comma,
        string type,
        postproc cell content/.code={%
                \pgfkeysalso{@cell content=\rule{0cm}{2.4ex}%
                \pgfmathsetmacro\y{min(100,max(0,round(##1 * 0.5)))}\edef\temp{\noexpand\cellcolor{blue!\y}}\temp%
                ##1}%
                }
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}\caption{Colors}
\centering
\pgfplotstabletypeset[color cells]{
a,b,c,d
50,300,200,100
20,0,100,200
}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

(Note: once I'd gotten that working, it complained about numbers being out of range so I truncated the possible values for `\y` to within the range `[0,100]`)

[image: table with colours set by contents]

Comment: Sorry to ask, but I'm kind of new to this. So the `\edef` makes the `\temp` macro to expand to what's inside it when call it, and the `\noexpand` makes it print the `\cellcolor` into the global macro, and the `\y` macro will expand as expected. Did I get it right? I was trying to achieve that behavior but didn't know how. I try putting a naive `\expand` but didn't work.