# Enhancing heatmap of triangular/sparse matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfplotstable

This is a follow-up question to:
[Heatmap of a triangular matrix (or a sparse matrix)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96403/heatmap-of-a-triangular-matrix-or-a-sparse-matrix)
(where also the code is taken from)

**What I want to achieve (Excel draft):**

[image: What I want to achieve]

**What I got so far (see code at bottom):**

[image: What I got so far]

**What is missing:**

- Axis description with "Some Text"
- Removing the "xxx" hack to get the first column being recognized as strings

**Possible solution for removing the "xxx" hack:**
I found that "automatic column numbering" was done here:
[Diverging color scale for a table heatmap](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/368751/diverging-color-scale-for-a-table-heatmap) and my dream solution would be not only incorporating it to my heatmap but also extending it with "automatic row numbering".

**Current Code:**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotstableset{
    /color cells/min/.initial=0,
    /color cells/max/.initial=1000,
    /color cells/textcolor/.initial=,
    %
    % Usage: 'color cells={min=<value which is mapped to lowest color>, 
    %   max = <value which is mapped to largest>}
    color cells/.code={%
        \pgfqkeys{/color cells}{#1}%
        \pgfkeysalso{%
            postproc cell content/.code={%
                %
                \begingroup
                %
                % acquire the value before any number printer changed
                % it:
                \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@preprocessed cell content}\value
                \ifx\value\empty
                \endgroup
                \else
                \pgfmathfloatparsenumber{\value}%
                \pgfmathfloattofixed{\pgfmathresult}%
                \let\value=\pgfmathresult
                %
                % map that value:
                \pgfplotscolormapaccess
                [\pgfkeysvalueof{/color cells/min}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/color cells/max}]%
                {\value}%
                {\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/colormap name}}%
                % now, \pgfmathresult contains {<R>,<G>,<B>}
                % 
                % acquire the value AFTER any preprocessor or
                % typesetter (like number printer) worked on it:
                \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}\typesetvalue
                \pgfkeysgetvalue{/color cells/textcolor}\textcolorvalue
                %
                % tex-expansion control
                % see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12668/where-do-i-start-latex-programming/27589#27589
                \toks0=\expandafter{\typesetvalue}%
                \xdef\temp{%
                    \noexpand\pgfkeysalso{%
                        @cell content={%
                            \noexpand\cellcolor[rgb]{\pgfmathresult}%
                            \noexpand\definecolor{mapped color}{rgb}{\pgfmathresult}%
                            \ifx\textcolorvalue\empty
                            \else
                            \noexpand\color{\textcolorvalue}%
                            \fi
                            \the\toks0 %
                        }%
                    }%
                }%
                \endgroup
                \temp
                \fi
            }%
        }%
    }
}

\begin{document}


    \vrule\pgfplotstabletypeset[%
    color cells={min=365,max=375,textcolor=black},
    /pgfplots/colormap={orangewhiteorange}{rgb255=(255,170,0) color=(white) rgb255=(255,170,0)},
    /pgf/number format/fixed,
    /pgf/number format/precision=0,
    col sep=comma,
    columns/xxx/.style={reset styles,string type}%
    ]{%%%%%%%
        xxx, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
        0, 370.8, 371.2, 371.1, 370.9, 371.2, 371.6, 372.0
        1, 370.4, 370.3, 370.4, 370.7, 370.8, 371.4, 371.5
        2, 370.9, , 370.7, 370.9, 370.8, 371.2, 372.1
        3, 371.0, , , 368.1, 371.1, 368.8, 371.3
        4, 370.9, , , , 371.1, 371.4, 371.4
        5, 371.7, , , , , 371.1, 371.4
        6, 372.0, , , , , , 371.2
    }\vrule
\end{document}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way to do this by extending my code from [How to interpolate two colors in a cell?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/401370/how-to-interpolate-two-colors-in-a-cell/401404#401404) to produce:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage[table,x11names]{xcolor}
  \usepackage{collcell}
  \usepackage{array}
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \usepackage{pgfkeys}
  \usepackage{graphicx}

  % set up pgfkeys for controlling heat specifications
  \pgfkeys{/heat/.is family, /heat,
      Max colour/.initial = Green4,
      Min colour/.initial = Red1,
      max colour/.initial = SpringGreen3,
      min colour/.initial = Yellow1,
      text colour/.initial = black,
      Min color/.style = {Min colour=#1},% for our friends who can't spell
      Max color/.style = {Max colour=#1},
      min color/.style = {min colour=#1},
      max color/.style = {max colour=#1},
      text color/.style = {text colour=#1},
      min/.initial = -1,
      max/.initial = 1,
      slider/.code={%
         \tikz{\shade[left color=\HVal{min colour},%
                      right color=\HVal{max colour}]%
            (current page.south west) rectangle ++(#1,12pt);
         }%
      }%
  }
  \newcommand\Heatset[1]{\pgfkeys{/heat, #1}}
  \newcommand\HVal[1]{\pgfkeysvalueof{/heat/#1}}

  \newcolumntype{H}{>{\collectcell\Heat}r<{\endcollectcell}}
  \newcommand\Heat[1]{% \Heat{number in the interval [min, max] }
    \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax% empty cell
    \else%
      \pgfmathparse{int(100*(#1-\HVal{min})/(\HVal{max}-\HVal{min}))}% map number to [0,100]
      \ifnum\pgfmathresult>100% too big
        \edef\HeatCell{\noexpand\cellcolor{\HVal{Max colour}}}%
      \else\ifnum\pgfmathresult<0% too small
          \edef\HeatCell{\noexpand\cellcolor{\HVal{Min colour}}}%
        \else% between min and max
          \edef\HeatCell{\noexpand\cellcolor{\HVal{max colour}!\pgfmathresult!\HVal{min colour}}}%
        \fi%
      \fi%
      \HeatCell\textcolor{\HVal{text colour}}{$#1$}%
    \fi%
  }

  \begin{document}

  \Heatset{min=370,   % maximum value
           max=372,   % minimum value
           max colour=Burlywood2, % colour at maximum
           min colour=Snow1,      % colour at minimum
           Min colour=OrangeRed1, % colour for values below min
           Max colour=SeaGreen3   % colour for values above max
  }

  \begin{tabular}{ cc *7H }
          &  \multicolumn8c{\textsf{Some text}}\\
          & &\multicolumn1c{0}&\multicolumn1c{1}&\multicolumn1c{2}&\multicolumn1c{3}
            &\multicolumn1c{4}&\multicolumn1c{5}&\multicolumn1c{6}\\
          & 0& 370.8& 371.2& 371.1& 370.9& 371.2& 371.6& 372.0\\
          & 1& 370.4& 370.3& 370.4& 370.7& 370.8& 371.4& 371.5\\
          & 2& 370.9& & 370.7& 370.9& 370.8& 371.2& 372.1\\
          \rotatebox{90}{\makebox[0pt]{\textsf{Some text}}}
          & 3& 371.0& & & 368.1& 371.1& 368.8& 371.3\\
          & 4& 370.9& & & & 371.1& 371.4& 371.4\\
          & 5& 371.7& & & & & 371.1& 371.4\\
          & 6& 372.0& & & & & & 371.2\\
  \end{tabular}

  \end{document}
```

Some comments:

- In the code from [How to interpolate two colors in a cell?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/401370/how-to-interpolate-two-colors-in-a-cell/401404#401404), the colours etc can be set using the `\Heatset` command. The relevant lines in the MWE are:

  ```
  \Heatset{min=370,   % maximum value 
         max=372,   % minimum value
         max colour=Burlywood2, % colour at maximum
         min colour=Snow1,      % colour at minimum
         Min colour=OrangeRed1, % colour for values below min
         Max colour=SeaGreen3   % colour for values above max
  }
  ```
- The text along the top is easy: just put it inside a `\multicolumn`
- The side at the side is slightly trickier. The `\rotatebox` command from the [graphicx](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) package lets you rotate text but if you do this naively then the fourth row of the table with have the same height as `some text`. To get around this I have used `\makebox` to put the text in a box of width zero.
- The code `\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax` is a standard way to test if `#1` is empty
- If the number is above max or below min then the corresponding Max/Min colour is printed...there's no shading here