# Guide to draw charts (basic, pie, bar) from data

Tags: tikz-pgf, bar-chart, pgf-pie

I went through the examples of using PSTricks and TikZ for drawing pie and bar chart. They looked quiet complicated to me. Is there any simple guide (blogs/text) to drawing these charts using PDFLaTeX. Learning to use gnuplot will be too much for a small presentation I am trying to create!

Comment: You could have a look at package `pgfplots`

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The [`pgfplots`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgfplots) manual gives a lot of information and tutorials- you'll also find a lot of great examples on this site.

Here's a humble tutorial on how I created the following bar graph, which I used in answering [How to clarify and enliven a dense table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141087/how-to-clarify-and-enliven-a-dense-table) using the wonderful [`pgfplots`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgfplots) package; the complete code is given at the end.

[image: bargraph]

### Reading the data

The first objective is to read the data- because the data came from a `LaTeX` table, we can tell `pgfplots` to separate columns by `&` and rows by `\\`. There are a *lot* of other options for reading data, including Comma Separated Value files (.csv), for example.

```
\pgfplotstableread[row sep=\\,col sep=&]{
    interval & carT & carD & carR \\
    0--2     & 1.2  & 0.1  & 0.2  \\
    2--5     & 12.8 & 3.8  & 4.9  \\
    5--10    & 15.5 & 10.4 & 13.4 \\
    10--20   & 14.0 & 17.3 & 22.2 \\
    20--50   & 7.9  & 21.1 & 27.0 \\
    50+      & 3.0  & 22.3 & 28.6 \\
    }\mydata
```

We can now access this in `pgfplots` commands using `\mydata`.

## A basic plot

We can make a very basic bar chart by using

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            ybar,
            symbolic x coords={0--2,2--5,5--10,10--20,20--50,50+},
            xtick=data,
        ]
        \addplot table[x=interval,y=carT]{\mydata};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

which gives

[image: first attempt]

Notice that we had to tell it to use the *symbolic* `x coords` so that it knew to use the values from the `interval` column on the horizontal axis.

## Adding more bars

We can easily add the other bars by using more `addplot` commands

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            ybar,
            symbolic x coords={0--2,2--5,5--10,10--20,20--50,50+},
        ]
        \addplot table[x=interval,y=carT]{\mydata};
        \addplot table[x=interval,y=carD]{\mydata};
        \addplot table[x=interval,y=carR]{\mydata};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

which gives

[image: more bars]

Notice that we kept `x=interval` and *changed* the `y=` to suit the appropriate columns.

## Adding more details

We can add a few more details such as the numbering near the top of each bar, and a legend by using `nodes near coords` and `\legend` respectively

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            ybar,
            symbolic x coords={0--2,2--5,5--10,10--20,20--50,50+},
            xtick=data,
            nodes near coords,
        ]
        \addplot table[x=interval,y=carT]{\mydata};
        \addplot table[x=interval,y=carD]{\mydata};
        \addplot table[x=interval,y=carR]{\mydata};
        \legend{Trips, Distance, Energy}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This gives

[image: nodes near coords and legend]

## Final tweaks

It's a little cramped together, so let's specify the `width`, `height`, and viewing window; we can also move the `legend` around and specify a label for the `y-axis`

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            ybar,
            bar width=.5cm,
            width=\textwidth,
            height=.5\textwidth,
            legend style={at={(0.5,1)},
                anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
            symbolic x coords={0--2,2--5,5--10,10--20,20--50,50+},
            xtick=data,
            nodes near coords,
            nodes near coords align={vertical},
            ymin=0,ymax=35,
            ylabel={\%},
        ]
        \addplot table[x=interval,y=carT]{\mydata};
        \addplot table[x=interval,y=carD]{\mydata};
        \addplot table[x=interval,y=carR]{\mydata};
        \legend{Trips, Distance, Energy}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Here's the result

[image: final result]

There are lot of other keys that you can use to tweak the look and feel of your chart- explore the manual and this site for more information.

## Complete MWE

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[row sep=\\,col sep=&]{
    interval & carT & carD & carR \\
    0--2     & 1.2  & 0.1  & 0.2  \\
    2--5     & 12.8 & 3.8  & 4.9  \\
    5--10    & 15.5 & 10.4 & 13.4 \\
    10--20   & 14.0 & 17.3 & 22.2 \\
    20--50   & 7.9  & 21.1 & 27.0 \\
    50+      & 3.0  & 22.3 & 28.6 \\
    }\mydata

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            ybar,
            bar width=.5cm,
            width=\textwidth,
            height=.5\textwidth,
            legend style={at={(0.5,1)},
                anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
            symbolic x coords={0--2,2--5,5--10,10--20,20--50,50+},
            xtick=data,
            nodes near coords,
            nodes near coords align={vertical},
            ymin=0,ymax=35,
            ylabel={\%},
        ]
        \addplot table[x=interval,y=carT]{\mydata};
        \addplot table[x=interval,y=carD]{\mydata};
        \addplot table[x=interval,y=carR]{\mydata};
        \legend{Trips, Distance, Energy}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm sorry for reviving an old topic, but the description of the table goes on the preamble of the document?

Comment: if x is not interval, (name, for example), what should I put into table[x=interval,y=carR]{\mydata};

Comment: @Tuma Yes, that is recommended.

Comment: @HahaTTpro Then table[x=name,y=othername]{\morenames};

Answer (score 4):

PGF has a wonderful site with lots of examples and explanations (Look at the bottom of the site). [Here](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/). TEXample is a page with structured examples. [Here](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/). PSTricks has a page with examples and 2D/3D gallery. [Here](http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi). Also on http://tex.stackexchange.com you can find many references. Use the search function with your keywords.