# Changing commas and dot on bar graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart

Here's what I have right now:

[image]

Is there a way to change commas for dots and vice versa? This table was made using the  answer from [this question,](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156964/guide-to-draw-charts-basic-pie-bar-from-data) so it's basically the same thing.

This isnt't an mwe, but here's the code for the graph:

```
\pgfplotstableread[row sep=\\,col sep=&]{
    interval & montecarlo & random\\
    1   & 3531.5  & 3.5 \\
    2   & 4088.5  & 1.08 \\
    3   & 4025.2  & 0.85 \\
    4   & 4049.7  & 1.056 \\
    5   & 4034.6  & 0.7\\
    6   & 4088.1  & 0.9 \\
    7   & 4043.5  & 0.3 \\
    8   & 4070.0  & 0.4\\
    9   & 4058.3  & 0.42\\
    10  & 4045.6  & 0.5\\
}\mydata

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[ybar, symbolic x coords={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},
            xtick=data, nodes near coords,width=\textwidth, font=\footnotesize]
        \addplot table [x=interval, y=montecarlo]{\mydata};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Tempos médios de deliberação do jogador Monte Carlo por partida} \label{montecarlotempos}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: I get an error when i edit the numbers: ` Could not parse input '3.531,5' as a floating point number, sorry.` I guess they have to be written in american style, with dots for decimals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the axis options use the following:

```
/pgf/number format/1000 sep={.},/pgf/number format/use comma,
```

> ... set /pgf/number format/use comma to set the comma as the decimal separator, and /pgf/number format/1000 sep={} to suppress separators for the groups of thousands.

See [`Jake answer`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31278/75648).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}    
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread[row sep=\\,col sep=&]{
    interval & montecarlo & random\\
    1   & 3531.5  & 3.5 \\
    2   & 4088.5  & 1.08 \\
    3   & 4025.2  & 0.85 \\
    4   & 4049.7  & 1.056 \\
    5   & 4034.6  & 0.7\\
    6   & 4088.1  & 0.9 \\
    7   & 4043.5  & 0.3 \\
    8   & 4070.0  & 0.4\\
    9   & 4058.3  & 0.42\\
    10  & 4045.6  & 0.5\\
}\mydata

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[ybar,/pgf/number format/1000 sep={.},/pgf/number format/use comma, symbolic x coords={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},
            xtick=data, nodes near coords,width=\textwidth, font=\footnotesize]
        \addplot table [x=interval, y=montecarlo]{\mydata};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Tempos médios de deliberação do jogador Monte Carlo por partida} \label{montecarlotempos}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]