# Bar on the side go out of bound when increase bar width

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart

I copy the code from [Guide to draw charts (basic, pie, bar) from data](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156964/guide-to-draw-charts-basic-pie-bar-from-data) and customize (just change the data value).

The bar width is too thin so the percentage overlap on each other.
[image: img1]
So, I increase the bar width
[image: img2]
Then 2 bar on the side of chart go outside (almost half)

How to fix that ?

Here is full source code that cause the problem (picture 2)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\title{draw_chart}
\author{Thien Thai}
\date{August 2017}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[row sep=\\,col sep=&]{
    interval & carT & carD & carR \\
    0--2     & 51.92  & 50.84  &  51.7 \\
    2--5     & 51 & 50.53  & 50  \\
    5--10    & 51.53 & 51.51 & 52.46 \\
    }\mydata

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            ybar,
            bar width=0.7cm,
            width=\textwidth,
            height=.5\textwidth,
            legend style={at={(0.5,1)},
                anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
            symbolic x coords={0--2,2--5,5--10},
            xtick=data,
            nodes near coords,
            nodes near coords align={vertical},
            ymin=49.5,ymax=53,
            ylabel={},
        ]
        \addplot table[x=interval,y=carT]{\mydata};
        \addplot table[x=interval,y=carD]{\mydata};
        \addplot table[x=interval,y=carR]{\mydata};
        \legend{Trips, Distance, Energy}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Look for `enlarge x limits`. Try e.g. `enlarge x limits={abs=0.5}`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. may I have full source code. I am newbie.

Comment: Just add what I wrote there to the `axis` options, e.g. right after `ylabel={},`

Comment: I would suggest `bar width=.8cm` and `enlarge x limits={abs=2*\pgfplotbarwidth}`. Additional remark:  set `compat` for `pgfplots`: `\usepackage{pgfplots}` directly followed by `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}` (1.15 is the current version) or `\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest `bar width=.8cm` and `enlarge x limits={abs=2*\pgfplotbarwidth}`.

Additional remark: set compat for pgfplots: \usepackage{pgfplots} directly followed by `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}` (1.15 is the current version) or `\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}`.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{pgfplots}% loads also tikz
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}%<- added

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\title{draw_chart}
\author{Thien Thai}
\date{August 2017}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread[row sep=\\,col sep=&]{
    interval & carT & carD & carR \\
    0--2     & 51.92  & 50.84  &  51.7 \\
    2--5     & 51 & 50.53  & 50  \\
    5--10    & 51.53 & 51.51 & 52.46 \\
    }\mydata

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            ybar,
            bar width=0.8cm,%<- changed
            width=\textwidth,
            height=.5\textwidth,
            legend style={at={(0.5,1)},
                anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
            symbolic x coords={0--2,2--5,5--10},
            xtick=data,
            nodes near coords,
            nodes near coords align={vertical},
            ymin=49.5,ymax=53,
            ylabel={},
            enlarge x limits={abs=2*\pgfplotbarwidth}
        ]
        \addplot table[x=interval,y=carT]{\mydata};
        \addplot table[x=interval,y=carD]{\mydata};
        \addplot table[x=interval,y=carR]{\mydata};
        \legend{Trips, Distance, Energy}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Maybe you want to add

```
nodes near coords style={/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=2},
```

to the `axis` options to get

[image]

Or with `precision=1`:

[image]