# 3D bar chart with pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, 3d, bar-chart

I want to draw a three-dimensional bar chart. I used this MWE code to draw two-dimensionally. Is it possible to draw in 3D like the last photo?

MWE:([Source](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156964/guide-to-draw-charts-basic-pie-bar-from-data))

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    
    \pgfplotstableread[row sep=\\,col sep=&]{
        interval    & carT  & carD  & carR \\
        Type A      & 10    & 15    & 20 \\
        Type B      & 8     & 6     & 12 \\
        Type C      & 5     & 8     & 10 \\
        }\mydata
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
                ybar,
                bar width=.5cm,
                width=\textwidth,
                height=.5\textwidth,
                legend style={at={(0.5,1)},
                    anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
                symbolic x coords={Type A, Type B, Type C},
                xtick=data,
                nodes near coords,
                nodes near coords align={vertical},
                ymin=0,ymax=35,
            ]
            \addplot table[x=interval,y=carT]{\mydata};
            \addplot table[x=interval,y=carD]{\mydata};
            \addplot table[x=interval,y=carR]{\mydata};
            \legend{AA, BB, CC}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result is:

[image]

I want this output:

[image]

Comment: I don't know a simple way to do it. But I also don't see a *reason* why on should want to draw 3-dimensional bars in a 2-dimentional axis. The reason is that you don't add any more *information* by drawing them in 3d, but only make it harder to read values. In fact if it wouldn't be written that e.g. the first bar has a value of 10, I would have guessed that it is below 10 ... (Please also have a look at [chapter 7 of the TikZ manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf#section.7).)

Comment: @StefanPinnow, Your explanation was so convincing. I agree with you now! Thanks so much.