# \pgfplotstabletypeset heatmap: logarithmic scale

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable, pgfmath

I am trying to create my own rendition of [this heatmap](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/83865/31877).
My values range anywhere from `1` to `783764`. I want to plot them as colors on a logarithmically (base10) scaled colormap. So the values' logarithmic representations should range from `0` to `~5.894`.

When I set the max value `color cells={min=1,max=783764}`, I get the following error

> ! Dimension too large.
>   <to be read again>
>   \relax
>   l.104 ]{data.csv}

Through experimentation I have fond that `16383` appears to be the maximum value that does *not* give me an error. Since I don't know how to make my intended maximum of `783764` work, I attempted to do some preprocessing (see [pgfplotstable docs](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplotstable.pdf) Sec. 3.3), and pull all my values through my own `lg10` function: `preproc/expr={lg10(##1)}`
However, *that* then gave me another error:

> ! Package PGF Math Error: Sorry, an internal routine of the floating point unit got an ill-formatted floating point number `1'.
>   The unreadable part was near '1'..

First of all, this is weird, since there is no value `1` in the data table that I tried this on. Secondly, I tried appending `.0` to all my (integer) values, but that made no difference.

**How can I make this work?**

Here's my Minimum non-working example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\listfiles
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.colormaps}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/83865/31877
\pgfplotstableset{
    /color cells/min/.initial=0,
    /color cells/max/.initial=1000,
    /color cells/textcolor/.initial=,
    %
    % Usage: 'color cells={min=<value which is mapped to lowest color>, 
    %   max = <value which is mapped to largest>}
    color cells/.code={%
        \pgfqkeys{/color cells}{#1}%
        \pgfkeysalso{%
            postproc cell content/.code={%
                \begingroup
                % acquire the value before any number printer changed it:
                \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@preprocessed cell content}\value
                \ifx\value\empty
                    \endgroup
                \else
                \pgfmathfloatparsenumber{\value}%
                \pgfmathfloattofixed{\pgfmathresult}%
                \let\value=\pgfmathresult
                % map that value:
                \pgfplotscolormapaccess
                    [\pgfkeysvalueof{/color cells/min}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/color cells/max}]
                    {\value}
                    {\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/colormap name}}%
                % now, \pgfmathresult contains {<R>,<G>,<B>}
                % 
                % acquire the value AFTER any preprocessor or
                % typesetter (like number printer) worked on it:
                \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}\typesetvalue
                \pgfkeysgetvalue{/color cells/textcolor}\textcolorvalue
                % tex-expansion control
                \toks0=\expandafter{\typesetvalue}%
                \xdef\temp{%
                    \noexpand\pgfkeysalso{%
                        @cell content={%
                            \noexpand\cellcolor[rgb]{\pgfmathresult}%
                            \noexpand\definecolor{mapped color}{rgb}{\pgfmathresult}%
                            \ifx\textcolorvalue\empty
                            \else
                                \noexpand\color{\textcolorvalue}%
                            \fi
                            \the\toks0 %
                        }%
                    }%
                }%
                \endgroup
                \temp
                \fi
            }%
        }%
    }
}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{lg10}{1}{%
    \pgfmathparse{ln(#1)/ln(10)}%
}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
item,Xa,Xb,Ya,Yb,Za,Zc
a,2,,2,,,
b,,2,,,4,2
c,,5,,,,
d,2,,8,,,
e,,,,,5,5
f,,,,3,,
g,,2,,,,
h,6,,,4,,
i,,,4,,,
j,,,,,,2
k,,2,,,3,2
l,,,7,,,
m,,6,,3,,
n,,,,,,7
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}


\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    %font=\tiny,
    colorCell/.style={
        preproc/expr={lg10(##1)},%fails to work on ANY number
        color cells={min=1,max=16383}%max should be 783764
    },
    itemCell/.style={
        string type,
        column name={},
    },
    col sep=comma,
    columns={item,Xa,Xb,Ya,Yb,Za,Zc},
    columns/item/.style={itemCell},
    columns/Xa/.style={colorCell},
    columns/Xb/.style={colorCell},
    columns/Ya/.style={colorCell},
    columns/Yb/.style={colorCell},
    columns/Za/.style={colorCell},
    columns/Zb/.style={colorCell},
]{data.csv}

\end{document}
```

Comment: There are a few issues combined here. 16383 (all ones of a 14bit binary) is the max number TeX can handle. For larger numbers you need to handle the numbers with `fpu` library. Then when fpu is enabled, you need to parse that number such that it is converted to the mantissa exponent form then it is compatible.

Comment: While I know what you mean, I don't know how to make that happen. To my eyes, the docs are just not transparent enough to find my way through. Could you please write up an answer for this that shows me *how* you addressed the issues you identified?

Comment: I will surely try if I can spare some time but most probably our wizards would come to rescue in the meantime.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is in the style posted at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/83865/31877 : apparently, the color map access method expects a number which is *not* in float representation. A quickfix would be to write `\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}` into the `color cells` style.

But: I suppose you want to typeset the raw number, not its log, right? You could also apply the log inside of the `color cells` style. That's what I did here - it does not need a special preprocessing step:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\listfiles
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.colormaps}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/83865/31877
\pgfplotstableset{
    /color cells/min/.initial=0,
    /color cells/max/.initial=1000,
    /color cells/textcolor/.initial=,
    %
    % Usage: 'color cells={min=<value which is mapped to lowest color>, 
    %   max = <value which is mapped to largest>}
    color cells/.code={%
        \pgfqkeys{/color cells}{#1}%
        \pgfkeysalso{%
            postproc cell content/.code={%
                \begingroup
                % acquire the value before any number printer changed it:
                \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@preprocessed cell content}\value
                \ifx\value\empty
                    \endgroup
                \else
                \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true}%
                %\pgfmathfloatparsenumber{\value}%
                \pgfmathparse{log10(\value)}%
                \pgfmathfloattofixed{\pgfmathresult}%
                \let\value=\pgfmathresult
                \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}% this here was the problem
                % map that value:
                \pgfplotscolormapaccess
                    [\pgfkeysvalueof{/color cells/min}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/color cells/max}]
                    {\value}
                    {\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/colormap name}}%
                % now, \pgfmathresult contains {<R>,<G>,<B>}
                % 
                % acquire the value AFTER any preprocessor or
                % typesetter (like number printer) worked on it:
                \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}\typesetvalue
                \pgfkeysgetvalue{/color cells/textcolor}\textcolorvalue
                % tex-expansion control
                \toks0=\expandafter{\typesetvalue}%
                \xdef\temp{%
                    \noexpand\pgfkeysalso{%
                        @cell content={%
                            \noexpand\cellcolor[rgb]{\pgfmathresult}%
                            \noexpand\definecolor{mapped color}{rgb}{\pgfmathresult}%
                            \ifx\textcolorvalue\empty
                            \else
                                \noexpand\color{\textcolorvalue}%
                            \fi
                            \the\toks0 %
                        }%
                    }%
                }%
                \endgroup
                \temp
                \fi
            }%
        }%
    }
}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{lg10}{1}{%
    \pgfmathparse{ln(#1)/ln(10)}%
}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
item,Xa,Xb,Ya,Yb,Za,Zc
a,2,,2,,,
b,,2,,,4,2
c,,5,,,,
d,2,,8,,,
e,,,,,5,5
f,,,,3,,
g,,2,,,,
h,6,,,4,,
i,,,4,,,
j,,,,,,2
k,,2,,,3,2
l,,,7,,,
m,,6,,3,,
n,,,,,,7
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}


\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    %font=\tiny,
    colorCell/.style={
      %  preproc/expr={lg10(##1)},%fails to work on ANY number
        color cells={min=0.3,max=0.85}%max should be 783764
    },
    itemCell/.style={
        string type,
        column name={},
    },
    col sep=comma,
    columns={item,Xa,Xb,Ya,Yb,Za,Zc},
    columns/item/.style={itemCell},
    columns/Xa/.style={colorCell},
    columns/Xb/.style={colorCell},
    columns/Ya/.style={colorCell},
    columns/Yb/.style={colorCell},
    columns/Za/.style={colorCell},
    columns/Zc/.style={colorCell},
]{data.csv}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works great. I changed the `max` to `5.9` to accommodate the `783764` I have in my actual situation.