# pgfplotstable column width & row height

Tags: pgfplotstable, width, height

I am drawing a large heatmap containing only colors using `\pgfplotstabletypeset`. The table contains 103 columns, and 111 rows, **which I am trying to squeeze in the area of `13cm * 16cm`**.
In order to save horizontal space, I have rotated the labels in the first row by 90 degrees, but the columns are still much too wide.
Simultaneously, rows are too tall.

**I would like to specify table cell width and height.**
I'm not worried about the labels in the 1st row/column becoming super-tiny as a result of this.
How do I do that?

Below, you'll find my MWE. It's inspired by [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158985/31877).
The only thing I found regarding the adjustment of column widths in pgfplotstable can be found in Sec. 2.3 of the [pgfplotstablr docs](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplotstable.pdf). I already applied that in my MWE, but it doesn't do much in my favor.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\listfiles
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.colormaps}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\pgfplotsset{
    colormap={myCustomColorMap}{
        color(0)=(blue);
        color(1)=(red);
    },
}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158985/31877
\pgfplotstableset{
    /color cells/min/.initial=0,
    /color cells/max/.initial=1000,
    /color cells/textcolor/.initial=,
    /color cells/colormap name/.initial=,% this was added
    %
    % Usage: 'color cells={min=<value which is mapped to lowest color>, 
    %   max = <value which is mapped to largest>}
    color cells/.code={%
        \pgfqkeys{/color cells}{#1}%
        \pgfkeysalso{%
            postproc cell content/.code={%
                \begingroup
                % acquire the value before any number printer changed it:
                \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@preprocessed cell content}\value
                \ifx\value\empty
                    \endgroup
                \else
                \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true}%
                \pgfmathparse{log10(\value)}%
                \pgfmathfloattofixed{\pgfmathresult}%
                \let\value=\pgfmathresult
                \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}%
                % map that value:
                \pgfplotscolormapaccess
                    [\pgfkeysvalueof{/color cells/min}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/color cells/max}]
                    {\value}
                    {\pgfkeysvalueof{/color cells/colormap name}}% I CHANGED THIS
                % now, \pgfmathresult contains {<R>,<G>,<B>}
                % 
                % acquire the value AFTER any preprocessor or
                % typesetter (like number printer) worked on it:
                \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}\typesetvalue
                \pgfkeysgetvalue{/color cells/textcolor}\textcolorvalue
                % tex-expansion control
                \toks0=\expandafter{\empty}%\typesetvalue}%
                \xdef\temp{%
                    \noexpand\pgfkeysalso{%
                        @cell content={%
                            \noexpand\cellcolor[rgb]{\pgfmathresult}%
                            \noexpand\definecolor{mapped color}{rgb}{\pgfmathresult}%
                            \ifx\textcolorvalue\empty
                            \else
                                \noexpand\color{\textcolorvalue}%
                            \fi
                            \the\toks0 %
                        }%
                    }%
                }%
                \endgroup
                \temp
                \fi
            }%
        }%
    }
}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{lg10}{1}{%
    \pgfmathparse{ln(#1)/ln(10)}%
}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
item,Xa,Xb,Ya,Yb,Za,Zb
a,2,,2,,783764,783764
b,,2,,,500000,500000
c,,5,,,100000,100000
d,2,,8,,20000,20000
e,,,,,10000,10000
f,,,,3,5000,5000
g,,2,,,1000,1000
h,6,,,4,500,500
i,,,4,,100,100
j,,,,,50,50
k,,2,,,10,10
l,,,7,,5,5
m,,6,,3,2,2
n,,,,,1,1
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1mm}}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    font=\tiny,
    every head row/.style={
        typeset cell/.code={
        \ifnum\pgfplotstablecol=1
            \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{&}%
        \else
            \ifnum\pgfplotstablecol=\pgfplotstablecols
                \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\rotatebox{90}{##1}\\}%
            \else
                \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\rotatebox{90}{##1}&}%
            \fi
        \fi
        }
    },
    %max=lg10(783764)
    colorCell/.style={
        column type=C,
        color cells={min=0,max=5.9,colormap name=myCustomColorMap}
    },
    itemCell/.style={
        string type,
        column name={},
    },
    col sep=comma,
    columns={item,Xa,Xb,Ya,Yb,Za,Zb},
    columns/item/.style={itemCell},
    columns/Xa/.style={colorCell},
    columns/Xb/.style={colorCell},
    columns/Ya/.style={colorCell},
    columns/Yb/.style={colorCell},
    columns/Za/.style={colorCell},
    columns/Zb/.style={colorCell},
]{data.csv}

\end{document}
```

[image: rendering]

Answer (score 3):

The easiest solution may be to put the `pgfplotstable` into the `\resizebox` command.
From [Wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables):

> The `graphicx` packages features the command `\resizebox{width}{height}{object}` which can be used with `tabular` to specify the height and width of a table.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\listfiles
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.colormaps}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\pgfplotsset{
    colormap={myCustomColorMap}{
        color(0)=(blue);
        color(1)=(red);
    },
}

% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158985/31877
\pgfplotstableset{
    /color cells/min/.initial=0,
    /color cells/max/.initial=1000,
    /color cells/textcolor/.initial=,
    /color cells/colormap name/.initial=,% this was added
    %
    % Usage: 'color cells={min=<value which is mapped to lowest color>, 
    %   max = <value which is mapped to largest>}
    color cells/.code={%
        \pgfqkeys{/color cells}{#1}%
        \pgfkeysalso{%
            postproc cell content/.code={%
                \begingroup
                % acquire the value before any number printer changed it:
                \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@preprocessed cell content}\value
                \ifx\value\empty
                    \endgroup
                \else
                \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true}%
                \pgfmathparse{log10(\value)}%
                \pgfmathfloattofixed{\pgfmathresult}%
                \let\value=\pgfmathresult
                \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}%
                % map that value:
                \pgfplotscolormapaccess
                    [\pgfkeysvalueof{/color cells/min}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/color cells/max}]
                    {\value}
                    {\pgfkeysvalueof{/color cells/colormap name}}% I CHANGED THIS
                % now, \pgfmathresult contains {<R>,<G>,<B>}
                % 
                % acquire the value AFTER any preprocessor or
                % typesetter (like number printer) worked on it:
                \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}\typesetvalue
                \pgfkeysgetvalue{/color cells/textcolor}\textcolorvalue
                % tex-expansion control
                \toks0=\expandafter{\empty}%\typesetvalue}%
                \xdef\temp{%
                    \noexpand\pgfkeysalso{%
                        @cell content={%
                            \noexpand\cellcolor[rgb]{\pgfmathresult}%
                            \noexpand\definecolor{mapped color}{rgb}{\pgfmathresult}%
                            \ifx\textcolorvalue\empty
                            \else
                                \noexpand\color{\textcolorvalue}%
                            \fi
                            \the\toks0 %
                        }%
                    }%
                }%
                \endgroup
                \temp
                \fi
            }%
        }%
    }
}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{lg10}{1}{%
    \pgfmathparse{ln(#1)/ln(10)}%
}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
item,Xa,Xb,Ya,Yb,Za,Zb
a,2,,2,,783764,783764
b,,2,,,500000,500000
c,,5,,,100000,100000
d,2,,8,,20000,20000
e,,,,,10000,10000
f,,,,3,5000,5000
g,,2,,,1000,1000
h,6,,,4,500,500
i,,,4,,100,100
j,,,,,50,50
k,,2,,,10,10
l,,,7,,5,5
m,,6,,3,2,2
n,,,,,1,1
\end{filecontents}

\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1mm}}



\begin{document}
\resizebox{3in}{2in}{\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    font=\tiny,
    every head row/.style={
        typeset cell/.code={
        \ifnum\pgfplotstablecol=1
            \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{&}%
        \else
            \ifnum\pgfplotstablecol=\pgfplotstablecols
                \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\rotatebox{90}{##1}\\}%
            \else
                \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\rotatebox{90}{##1}&}%
            \fi
        \fi
        }
    },
    %max=lg10(783764)
    colorCell/.style={
        column type=C,
        color cells={min=0,max=5.9,colormap name=myCustomColorMap}
    },
    itemCell/.style={
        string type,
        column name={},
    },
    col sep=comma,
    columns={item,Xa,Xb,Ya,Yb,Za,Zb},
    columns/item/.style={itemCell},
    columns/Xa/.style={colorCell},
    columns/Xb/.style={colorCell},
    columns/Ya/.style={colorCell},
    columns/Yb/.style={colorCell},
    columns/Za/.style={colorCell},
    columns/Zb/.style={colorCell},
]{data.csv}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

One strange thing about this though is that even though I specify the options `width=3in` and `height=2in` to `\resizebox`, for some reason my output has width 3.01 in and height 3.9 in.
I don't know why `\resizebox` gets the height wrong by a multiplicative factor.

Comment: I was considering that. But I'm a bit reluctant, since this destroys the aesthetically pleasing proportions of the font used; Even if the text becomes insanely tiny.

Answer (score 2):

Based on what I learned in [How to map value to color using TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159244/how-to-map-value-to-color-using-tikz), I am able to do what you want by using the `R` programming language to pre-process the input file, then to draw each rectangle using TikZ and a `\foreach` loop.
(The answer in [Need some help getting started with TikZ, groupplots and color mapping of matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134114/need-some-help-getting-started-with-tikz-groupplots-and-color-mapping-of-matrix) uses a similar approach where instead of using `pgfplotstable`, the answerer draws his own "table" using TikZ).
Unfortunately I don't know enough TeX to do all the processing in TeX, so I did the processing in `R`.
(But you could use your favorite programming language instead of `R`).

First, I save the input file as a text file `2014-02-09.txt`.

Next, I run an `R` script to compute the base-10 logs, and output the entries in the input file into a LaTeX list.
(Note: `R` is a widely used statistical programming language.)

```
temp <- read.table('2014-02-09.txt', sep=',', header = TRUE)

sink('2014-02-09-converted.tex')
prestring <- ''
cat('\\newcommand*{\\ListOfRectangles}{')
cat('%x/y/value\n')
for (i in 1:nrow(temp)) {
  for (j in 2:ncol(temp)) {
    value <- log(temp[i,j]) / log(10)
    if (!is.na(value)) {
      cat(sprintf('%s%d/%d/%.2f', prestring, j, i, value))
      prestring <- ',\n'
    }
  }
}
cat('%\n}')
sink()
```

The output is a file `2014-02-09-converted.tex` whose contents are:

```
\newcommand*{\ListOfRectangles}{%x/y/value
2/1/0.30,
4/1/0.30,
6/1/5.89,
7/1/5.89,
3/2/0.30,
6/2/5.70,
7/2/5.70,
3/3/0.70,
6/3/5.00,
7/3/5.00,
2/4/0.30,
4/4/0.90,
6/4/4.30,
7/4/4.30,
6/5/4.00,
7/5/4.00,
5/6/0.48,
6/6/3.70,
7/6/3.70,
3/7/0.30,
6/7/3.00,
7/7/3.00,
2/8/0.78,
5/8/0.60,
6/8/2.70,
7/8/2.70,
4/9/0.60,
6/9/2.00,
7/9/2.00,
6/10/1.70,
7/10/1.70,
3/11/0.30,
6/11/1.00,
7/11/1.00,
4/12/0.85,
6/12/0.70,
7/12/0.70,
3/13/0.78,
5/13/0.48,
6/13/0.30,
7/13/0.30,
6/14/0.00,
7/14/0.00%
}
```

Finally, I compile the LaTeX code which `\input`s the previously computed list.
Notice that by varying the `xscale` and `yscale` options you can change the size of the PDF output.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\input{2014-02-09-converted}

\begin{document}
% to change the output size of the PDF, change the xscale and yscale values.
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=0.5,yscale=0.3]
  \colorlet{color min}[rgb]{blue}
  \colorlet{color max}[rgb]{red}

  \def\min{0}
  \def\max{5.89}

  \foreach \sX/\sY/\myvalue in \ListOfRectangles {
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\lambda{(\max-\myvalue)/(\max-\min)*100}
    \colorlet{my color}[rgb]{color min!\lambda!color max}
    \fill[my color] (\sX, -\sY) rectangle +(1cm,1cm);
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]