# Make a large heatmap with gaps and tables between

Tags: tables, pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I am trying to make a large heatmap which looks like this with gaps and row or column names written in some of the cells. Empty cells are also present in the heat map. Can i make this using pgfplots? Which would be the best way? To make 6 different heatmaps, different tables and then align them accordingly or make a large heatmap and then insert row, column names and empty cells??
Please help!
[image]

Comment: possible starting point: [Drawing heatmaps using TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44868) It'd be great if you could post something for folks to work with; even something as minimal as the underlying structure of the table

Comment: What do the numbers 5 to 10 represent? What is a gray cell representing?

Comment: The numbers 5 to 10 are the sections of a particular class of a school. They don't need to be colored.