# Pgfplotstable and etoc don't recompile

Tags: pgfplotstable, etoc

My document compiled normally, but it seems that there is an incompatibility
between the packages etoc and pgfplots. The latex compiles, but not to recompile to get the references and the table of contents. I wrote this MWE.
(the heatmap code is from [Drawing heatmaps using TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44868/drawing-heatmaps-using-tikz))

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning}
\usepackage{etoc}
\usepackage{appendix}

\pgfplotstableset{
    /color cells/min/.initial=0,
    /color cells/max/.initial=1000,
    /color cells/textcolor/.initial=,
    %
    % Usage: 'color cells={min=<value which is mapped to lowest color>, 
    %   max = <value which is mapped to largest>}
    color cells/.code={%
        \pgfqkeys{/color cells}{#1}%
        \pgfkeysalso{%
            postproc cell content/.code={%
                %
                \begingroup
                %
                % acquire the value before any number printer changed
                % it:
                \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@preprocessed cell content}\value
                \ifx\value\empty
                    \endgroup
                \else
                \pgfmathfloatparsenumber{\value}%
                \pgfmathfloattofixed{\pgfmathresult}%
                \let\value=\pgfmathresult
                %
                % map that value:
                \pgfplotscolormapaccess
                    [\pgfkeysvalueof{/color cells/min}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/color cells/max}]
                    {\value}
                    {\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/colormap name}}%
                % now, \pgfmathresult contains {<R>,<G>,<B>}
                % 
                % acquire the value AFTER any preprocessor or
                % typesetter (like number printer) worked on it:
                \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}\typesetvalue
                \pgfkeysgetvalue{/color cells/textcolor}\textcolorvalue
                %
                % tex-expansion control
                % see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12668/where-do-i-start-latex-programming/27589#27589
                \toks0=\expandafter{\typesetvalue}%
                \xdef\temp{%
                    \noexpand\pgfkeysalso{%
                        @cell content={%
                            \noexpand\cellcolor[rgb]{\pgfmathresult}%
                            \noexpand\definecolor{mapped color}{rgb}{\pgfmathresult}%
                            \ifx\textcolorvalue\empty
                            \else
                                \noexpand\color{\textcolorvalue}%
                            \fi
                            \the\toks0 %
                        }%
                    }%
                }%
                \endgroup
                \temp
                \fi
            }%
        }%
    }
}

\begin{document}

\etoctableofcontents

\part{SOCIOECONOMIC}
\localtableofcontents
\chapter{EDUCATION}

Look the Table \ref{tab:mediatur}.

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Average class size - students per class}
\label{tab:mediatur}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[%
    color cells={min=28,max=35, textcolor= - mapped color!100! black},
    /pgfplots/colormap={whiteblue}{rgb255(0cm)=(255,255,255); rgb255(1cm)=(255,50,0)},
%
    col sep=&,
    row sep=\\,
% fix number format
    /pgf/number format/precision=1,
    /pgf/number format/fixed,
    /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,
    /pgf/number format/set decimal separator = {,},
    columns/EMPTY/.style={
        column name={},
        assign cell content/.code={
            \ifnum\pgfplotstablerow=0
                \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\multirow{2}{*}{##1}}%
            \else
                \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{}%
            \fi},reset styles, string type},
% row formatting
    every row no  0/.style = {before row = \bfseries Kindergarten\\\cmidrule{1-1}},
    every row no  2/.style = {before row = \bfseries Primary Education\\\cmidrule{1-1}},
    every row no 11/.style = {before row = \bfseries High School\\\cmidrule{1-1}},
%
    every head row/.style={before row=\toprule
\multirow{2}{*}{\bfseries Series} & \multicolumn{7}{c}{\bfseries Period}\\\cmidrule{2-8} ,after row=\midrule},
    every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
% columns formatting
    display columns/1/.style={column type = r},%
    display columns/2/.style={column type = r},%
    display columns/3/.style={column type = r},%
    display columns/4/.style={column type = r},%
    display columns/5/.style={column type = r},%
    display columns/6/.style={column type = r},%
    display columns/7/.style={column type = r},%
    display columns/8/.style={column type = r},%
]{
   EMPTY & 2007 & 2008 & 2009 & 2010 & 2011 & 2012 & 2013\\
%Kindergarten &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 
Nursery     & 15.7 & 17.5 & 15.8 & 17.7 & 18.7 & 17.4 & 17.1\\
Pre School & 20.0 & 20.0 & 20.1 & 20.9 & 19.5 & 20.2 & 19.9\\
%Primary Education 8 and 9 years  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 
 1st year    & 23.6 & 21.9 & 24.4 & 22.1 & 20.7 & 23.5 & 20.4\\
 2nd year    & 21.7 & 23.3 & 26.7 & 23.0 & 22.3 & 24.0 & 22.7\\
 3rd year    & 27.2 & 25.7 & 20.6 & 24.4 & 23.9 & 24.4 & 23.2\\
 4th year    & 24.8 & 24.6 & 24.7 & 24.2 & 24.4 & 23.9 & 24.4\\
 5th year    & 25.4 & 29.0 & 27.7 & 27.1 & 22.3 & 24.1 & 24.1\\
 6th year    & 31.7 & 33.5 & 29.7 & 29.8 & 31.4 & 26.5 & 26.3\\
 7th year    & 32.2 & 32.8 & 33.3 & 30.1 & 29.1 & 29.3 & 25.8\\
 8th year    & 31.3 & 34.2 & 33.1 & 30.8 & 28.9 & 29.6 & 30.3\\
 9th year    & 33.7 & 36.6 & 33.2 & 32.1 & 32.4 & 29.6 & 29.5\\
%High School  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 
 1st grade  & 39.1 & 38.9 & 36.3 & 34.2 & 32.4 & 35.1 & 31.2\\
 2nd grade  & 33.2 & 34.8 & 28.7 & 32.0 & 30.3 & 25.6 & 26.9\\
 3rd grade  & 29.6 & 30.4 & 29.5 & 28.2 & 29.5 & 28.7 & 27.6\\
 4th grade  &   0  & 28.0 & 23.7 & 18.7 & 20.7 & 24.3 & 17.8\\
}
\end{table}


\appendix

\part*{APPENDICES}

\etoctoccontentsline*{appendixplaceholder}{APPENDIX}{-1}
\etocsettocdepth{chapter}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Alph{chapter}}
\setcounter{chapter}{0} 

\localtableofcontents

\chapter{Document One}
Test 1.

\chapter{Document Two}
Test 2.

\end{document}
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: This is not an MWE. If you suspect the incompatibility of two packages, then you are loading 5 packages too much in order to show that error. You are tagging `pgfplotstable` so everything around the table should not be needed. And the error will appear for one table line as well... (just giving some tips in order to reduce the code and to get an answer more quickly).

Comment: It is not about `pgfplotstable` package. `etoc` has problems in the appendix. Remove the appendices and delete the `.aux` file and it compiles.

Comment: @percusse That sounds much like an answer...

Comment: @percusse see my answer, the problem originated in a user `\etoctoccontentsline*` command with a dummy sectioning unit name `appendixplaceholder` which had not been declared to `etoc`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was with your

```
\etoctoccontentsline*{appendixplaceholder}{APPENDIX}{-1}
```

near the end of the document. The problem is simply that `appendixplaceholder` stands for some dummy sectioning unit but has not been declared to `etoc`. To fix this you could add:

```
\etocsetlevel{appendixplaceholder}{6} % 6 = invisible
```

in the preamble, and then before the `\localtableofcontents` <strike>in the Appendix part</strike>, or rather right after the main TOC, you would insert `\etocsetlevel{appendixplaceholder}{-1}`. (my hesitation is because I am not sure what you were trying to achieve; avoid `Appendix` heading to appear in the main `TOC` but gets the two appendices nevertheless listed?)

This being said a leaner solution is to forget entirely about this `appendixplaceholder` and `\etoctoccontentsline*` business and do simply this:

```
\appendix

\part*{APPENDICES}

\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{APPENDIX}% add unnumbered part to TOC

\etocsettocdepth{chapter}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Alph{chapter}}
\setcounter{chapter}{0} 

\localtableofcontents % works because there is the APPENDIX as part in TOC
```

This produces this global TOC:

[image: global TOC with Appendices]

and the local one in the Appendix part too. Works with `hyperref` loaded too.