# colour coding of 2-d-data

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Imagine the following requirement: There is a rectangular matrix of variable
size with integer elements. These data are located in an ascii file. I need
to get it into a TikZ graphic (1) where the data are shown in a colour coded
way (2). I actually do not want to use pgfplots as the kind of graphic is
quite restrained and I think it would be too difficult to do this with
pgfplots.

Which would be the easiest way to (1) get the data and to (2) colour the data,
whereas each data should be shown as a small rectangle with the respective
colour?

I would appreciate it very much if you could give me a hint to the required or
most appropriate packages, I do not necessarily ask for a complete solution.
But of course I would like to show the solution (and perhaps ask some
additional questions -;)).

New day, new luck. I think my work made a good progress (thanks to you),
but now I am quite bewildered what pgfplots does with my data. The enclosed
example leads to the following result. If you have a closer look and compare
the data with the graph you will find that there are main discrepancies.
For example: the data contains only one 'central column' which is doubled
in the graph (why?). Furthermore the orange lines should be in the order
light orange-dark orange, but there is light-dark-light (why?).

[image]

Do you have any ideas?

Another, smaller, issue: Is there any way to tell pgfplots the size of the
graph alone? I believe that the size is with axes, although they are not
active.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{RDM.dat}
0 0 -71
1 0 -44
2 0 -42
3 0 -45
4 0 -43
5 0 -51
6 0 -53
7 0 -46
8 0 -40
9 0 -51
10 0 -35
11 0 -42
12 0 -65
13 0 -51
14 0 -43
15 0 -43
16 0 -48
17 0 -43
18 0 -43
19 0 -51
20 0 -65
21 0 -42
22 0 -35
23 0 -51
24 0 -40
25 0 -46
26 0 -53
27 0 -51
28 0 -43
29 0 -45
30 0 -42
31 0 -44

0 1 -44
1 1 -49
2 1 -45
3 1 -45
4 1 -43
5 1 -50
6 1 -43
7 1 -51
8 1 -44
9 1 -43
10 1 -41
11 1 -52
12 1 -43
13 1 -64
14 1 -46
15 1 -50
16 1 -40
17 1 -50
18 1 -46
19 1 -64
20 1 -43
21 1 -52
22 1 -41
23 1 -43
24 1 -44
25 1 -51
26 1 -43
27 1 -50
28 1 -43
29 1 -45
30 1 -45
31 1 -49

0 2 -65
1 2 -44
2 2 -40
3 2 -53
4 2 -53
5 2 -48
6 2 -43
7 2 -44
8 2 -55
9 2 -43
10 2 -45
11 2 -65
12 2 -46
13 2 -37
14 2 -39
15 2 -38
16 2 -50
17 2 -38
18 2 -39
19 2 -37
20 2 -46
21 2 -65
22 2 -45
23 2 -43
24 2 -55
25 2 -44
26 2 -43
27 2 -48
28 2 -53
29 2 -53
30 2 -40
31 2 -44

0 3 -40
1 3 -43
2 3 -42
3 3 -50
4 3 -41
5 3 -54
6 3 -44
7 3 -49
8 3 -40
9 3 -42
10 3 -45
11 3 -37
12 3 -49
13 3 -43
14 3 -49
15 3 -41
16 3 -57
17 3 -41
18 3 -49
19 3 -43
20 3 -49
21 3 -37
22 3 -45
23 3 -42
24 3 -40
25 3 -49
26 3 -44
27 3 -54
28 3 -41
29 3 -50
30 3 -42
31 3 -43

0 4 -41
1 4 -71
2 4 -43
3 4 -49
4 4 -49
5 4 -58
6 4 -47
7 4 -52
8 4 -39
9 4 -51
10 4 -51
11 4 -53
12 4 -45
13 4 -60
14 4 -43
15 4 -46
16 4 -39
17 4 -46
18 4 -43
19 4 -60
20 4 -45
21 4 -53
22 4 -51
23 4 -51
24 4 -39
25 4 -52
26 4 -47
27 4 -58
28 4 -49
29 4 -49
30 4 -43
31 4 -71

0 5 -45
1 5 -51
2 5 -49
3 5 -43
4 5 -45
5 5 -37
6 5 -48
7 5 -48
8 5 -41
9 5 -48
10 5 -45
11 5 -42
12 5 -46
13 5 -48
14 5 -51
15 5 -47
16 5 -40
17 5 -47
18 5 -51
19 5 -48
20 5 -46
21 5 -42
22 5 -45
23 5 -48
24 5 -41
25 5 -48
26 5 -48
27 5 -37
28 5 -45
29 5 -43
30 5 -49
31 5 -51

0 6 -46
1 6 -52
2 6 -49
3 6 -39
4 6 -47
5 6 -54
6 6 -47
7 6 -43
8 6 -48
9 6 -39
10 6 -43
11 6 -51
12 6 -40
13 6 -38
14 6 -53
15 6 -55
16 6 -65
17 6 -55
18 6 -53
19 6 -38
20 6 -40
21 6 -51
22 6 -43
23 6 -39
24 6 -48
25 6 -43
26 6 -47
27 6 -54
28 6 -47
29 6 -39
30 6 -49
31 6 -52

0 7 -54
1 7 -46
2 7 -55
3 7 -47
4 7 -44
5 7 -53
6 7 -40
7 7 -41
8 7 -43
9 7 -38
10 7 -45
11 7 -60
12 7 -40
13 7 -46
14 7 -44
15 7 -44
16 7 -45
17 7 -44
18 7 -44
19 7 -46
20 7 -40
21 7 -60
22 7 -45
23 7 -38
24 7 -43
25 7 -41
26 7 -40
27 7 -53
28 7 -44
29 7 -47
30 7 -55
31 7 -46

0 8 -52
1 8 -48
2 8 -42
3 8 -46
4 8 -47
5 8 -48
6 8 -42
7 8 -40
8 8 -53
9 8 -41
10 8 -40
11 8 -53
12 8 -48
13 8 -44
14 8 -50
15 8 -51
16 8 -50
17 8 -51
18 8 -50
19 8 -44
20 8 -48
21 8 -53
22 8 -40
23 8 -41
24 8 -53
25 8 -40
26 8 -42
27 8 -48
28 8 -47
29 8 -46
30 8 -42
31 8 -48

0 9 -65
1 9 -53
2 9 -45
3 9 -67
4 9 -45
5 9 -39
6 9 -50
7 9 -43
8 9 -53
9 9 -61
10 9 -44
11 9 -46
12 9 -44
13 9 -49
14 9 -47
15 9 -49
16 9 -39
17 9 -49
18 9 -47
19 9 -49
20 9 -44
21 9 -46
22 9 -44
23 9 -61
24 9 -53
25 9 -43
26 9 -50
27 9 -39
28 9 -45
29 9 -67
30 9 -45
31 9 -53

0 10 -42
1 10 -48
2 10 -46
3 10 -42
4 10 -51
5 10 -43
6 10 -44
7 10 -54
8 10 -41
9 10 -55
10 10 -41
11 10 -39
12 10 -47
13 10 -50
14 10 -42
15 10 -54
16 10 -47
17 10 -54
18 10 -42
19 10 -50
20 10 -47
21 10 -39
22 10 -41
23 10 -55
24 10 -41
25 10 -54
26 10 -44
27 10 -43
28 10 -51
29 10 -42
30 10 -46
31 10 -48

0 11 -48
1 11 -48
2 11 -43
3 11 -41
4 11 -47
5 11 -48
6 11 -52
7 11 -49
8 11 -43
9 11 -50
10 11 -43
11 11 -48
12 11 -48
13 11 -50
14 11 -46
15 11 -45
16 11 -60
17 11 -45
18 11 -46
19 11 -50
20 11 -48
21 11 -48
22 11 -43
23 11 -50
24 11 -43
25 11 -49
26 11 -52
27 11 -48
28 11 -47
29 11 -41
30 11 -43
31 11 -48

0 12 -45
1 12 -44
2 12 -38
3 12 -39
4 12 -42
5 12 -44
6 12 -51
7 12 -41
8 12 -50
9 12 -40
10 12 -58
11 12 -53
12 12 -46
13 12 -46
14 12 -39
15 12 -56
16 12 -42
17 12 -56
18 12 -39
19 12 -46
20 12 -46
21 12 -53
22 12 -58
23 12 -40
24 12 -50
25 12 -41
26 12 -51
27 12 -44
28 12 -42
29 12 -39
30 12 -38
31 12 -44

0 13 -66
1 13 -43
2 13 -52
3 13 -55
4 13 -56
5 13 -60
6 13 -51
7 13 -43
8 13 -42
9 13 -52
10 13 -41
11 13 -49
12 13 -40
13 13 -51
14 13 -47
15 13 -46
16 13 -65
17 13 -46
18 13 -47
19 13 -51
20 13 -40
21 13 -49
22 13 -41
23 13 -52
24 13 -42
25 13 -43
26 13 -51
27 13 -60
28 13 -56
29 13 -55
30 13 -52
31 13 -43

0 14 -49
1 14 -39
2 14 -42
3 14 -62
4 14 -44
5 14 -47
6 14 -40
7 14 -47
8 14 -45
9 14 -41
10 14 -45
11 14 -50
12 14 -45
13 14 -43
14 14 -45
15 14 -51
16 14 -82
17 14 -51
18 14 -45
19 14 -43
20 14 -45
21 14 -50
22 14 -45
23 14 -41
24 14 -45
25 14 -47
26 14 -40
27 14 -47
28 14 -44
29 14 -62
30 14 -42
31 14 -39

0 15 -45
1 15 -41
2 15 -55
3 15 -44
4 15 -41
5 15 -52
6 15 -43
7 15 -46
8 15 -49
9 15 -47
10 15 -51
11 15 -46
12 15 -49
13 15 -46
14 15 -44
15 15 -50
16 15 -65
17 15 -50
18 15 -44
19 15 -46
20 15 -49
21 15 -46
22 15 -51
23 15 -47
24 15 -49
25 15 -46
26 15 -43
27 15 -52
28 15 -41
29 15 -44
30 15 -55
31 15 -41

0 16 -63
1 16 -58
2 16 -51
3 16 -55
4 16 -47
5 16 -48
6 16 -43
7 16 -50
8 16 -46
9 16 -45
10 16 -46
11 16 -52
12 16 -50
13 16 -50
14 16 -50
15 16 -41
16 16 -45
17 16 -41
18 16 -50
19 16 -50
20 16 -50
21 16 -52
22 16 -46
23 16 -45
24 16 -46
25 16 -50
26 16 -43
27 16 -48
28 16 -47
29 16 -55
30 16 -51
31 16 -58

0 17 -44
1 17 -44
2 17 -44
3 17 -45
4 17 -62
5 17 -55
6 17 -48
7 17 -47
8 17 -46
9 17 -44
10 17 -51
11 17 -44
12 17 -48
13 17 -41
14 17 -50
15 17 -41
16 17 -56
17 17 -41
18 17 -50
19 17 -41
20 17 -48
21 17 -44
22 17 -51
23 17 -44
24 17 -46
25 17 -47
26 17 -48
27 17 -55
28 17 -62
29 17 -45
30 17 -44
31 17 -44

0 18 -53
1 18 -47
2 18 -49
3 18 -48
4 18 -51
5 18 -60
6 18 -53
7 18 -51
8 18 -42
9 18 -43
10 18 -52
11 18 -46
12 18 -51
13 18 -40
14 18 -44
15 18 -61
16 18 -51
17 18 -61
18 18 -44
19 18 -40
20 18 -51
21 18 -46
22 18 -52
23 18 -43
24 18 -42
25 18 -51
26 18 -53
27 18 -60
28 18 -51
29 18 -48
30 18 -49
31 18 -47

0 19 -43
1 19 -43
2 19 -48
3 19 -48
4 19 -39
5 19 -48
6 19 -51
7 19 -49
8 19 -47
9 19 -46
10 19 -55
11 19 -56
12 19 -52
13 19 -50
14 19 -44
15 19 -48
16 19 -47
17 19 -48
18 19 -44
19 19 -50
20 19 -52
21 19 -56
22 19 -55
23 19 -46
24 19 -47
25 19 -49
26 19 -51
27 19 -48
28 19 -39
29 19 -48
30 19 -48
31 19 -43

0 20 -51
1 20 -50
2 20 -45
3 20 -49
4 20 -45
5 20 -53
6 20 -58
7 20 -48
8 20 -48
9 20 -39
10 20 -48
11 20 -60
12 20 -48
13 20 -60
14 20 -45
15 20 -45
16 20 -47
17 20 -45
18 20 -45
19 20 -60
20 20 -48
21 20 -60
22 20 -48
23 20 -39
24 20 -48
25 20 -48
26 20 -58
27 20 -53
28 20 -45
29 20 -49
30 20 -45
31 20 -50

0 21 -38
1 21 -45
2 21 -47
3 21 -54
4 21 -46
5 21 -47
6 21 -44
7 21 -46
8 21 -44
9 21 -48
10 21 -41
11 21 -43
12 21 -54
13 21 -42
14 21 -49
15 21 -55
16 21 -65
17 21 -55
18 21 -49
19 21 -42
20 21 -54
21 21 -43
22 21 -41
23 21 -48
24 21 -44
25 21 -46
26 21 -44
27 21 -47
28 21 -46
29 21 -54
30 21 -47
31 21 -45

0 22 -51
1 22 -47
2 22 -54
3 22 -49
4 22 -44
5 22 -44
6 22 -50
7 22 -48
8 22 -61
9 22 -49
10 22 -42
11 22 -46
12 22 -46
13 22 -46
14 22 -51
15 22 -41
16 22 -71
17 22 -41
18 22 -51
19 22 -46
20 22 -46
21 22 -46
22 22 -42
23 22 -49
24 22 -61
25 22 -48
26 22 -50
27 22 -44
28 22 -44
29 22 -49
30 22 -54
31 22 -47

0 23 -44
1 23 -49
2 23 -40
3 23 -44
4 23 -48
5 23 -50
6 23 -43
7 23 -44
8 23 -44
9 23 -46
10 23 -49
11 23 -46
12 23 -43
13 23 -47
14 23 -40
15 23 -50
16 23 -47
17 23 -50
18 23 -40
19 23 -47
20 23 -43
21 23 -46
22 23 -49
23 23 -46
24 23 -44
25 23 -44
26 23 -43
27 23 -50
28 23 -48
29 23 -44
30 23 -40
31 23 -49

0 24 -73
1 24 -52
2 24 -41
3 24 -49
4 24 -47
5 24 -61
6 24 -54
7 24 -55
8 24 -49
9 24 -39
10 24 -39
11 24 -66
12 24 -47
13 24 -48
14 24 -49
15 24 -52
16 24 -67
17 24 -52
18 24 -49
19 24 -48
20 24 -47
21 24 -66
22 24 -39
23 24 -39
24 24 -49
25 24 -55
26 24 -54
27 24 -61
28 24 -47
29 24 -49
30 24 -41
31 24 -52

0 25 -48
1 25 -54
2 25 -42
3 25 -46
4 25 -41
5 25 -45
6 25 -44
7 25 -40
8 25 -45
9 25 -53
10 25 -43
11 25 -39
12 25 -37
13 25 -53
14 25 -46
15 25 -50
16 25 -57
17 25 -50
18 25 -46
19 25 -53
20 25 -37
21 25 -39
22 25 -43
23 25 -53
24 25 -45
25 25 -40
26 25 -44
27 25 -45
28 25 -41
29 25 -46
30 25 -42
31 25 -54

0 26 -48
1 26 -44
2 26 -51
3 26 -50
4 26 -42
5 26 -49
6 26 -49
7 26 -44
8 26 -43
9 26 -54
10 26 -48
11 26 -50
12 26 -46
13 26 -48
14 26 -44
15 26 -52
16 26 -58
17 26 -52
18 26 -44
19 26 -48
20 26 -46
21 26 -50
22 26 -48
23 26 -54
24 26 -43
25 26 -44
26 26 -49
27 26 -49
28 26 -42
29 26 -50
30 26 -51
31 26 -44

0 27 -56
1 27 -46
2 27 -50
3 27 -47
4 27 -46
5 27 -51
6 27 -50
7 27 -52
8 27 -41
9 27 -57
10 27 -49
11 27 -50
12 27 -47
13 27 -51
14 27 -43
15 27 -51
16 27 -40
17 27 -51
18 27 -43
19 27 -51
20 27 -47
21 27 -50
22 27 -49
23 27 -57
24 27 -41
25 27 -52
26 27 -50
27 27 -51
28 27 -46
29 27 -47
30 27 -50
31 27 -46

0 28 -59
1 28 -44
2 28 -49
3 28 -56
4 28 -54
5 28 -43
6 28 -49
7 28 -50
8 28 -54
9 28 -48
10 28 -39
11 28 -40
12 28 -43
13 28 -40
14 28 -39
15 28 -45
16 28 -47
17 28 -45
18 28 -39
19 28 -40
20 28 -43
21 28 -40
22 28 -39
23 28 -48
24 28 -54
25 28 -50
26 28 -49
27 28 -43
28 28 -54
29 28 -56
30 28 -49
31 28 -44

0 29 -53
1 29 -52
2 29 -64
3 29 -52
4 29 -50
5 29 -51
6 29 -40
7 29 -57
8 29 -60
9 29 -51
10 29 -47
11 29 -54
12 29 -51
13 29 -46
14 29 -52
15 29 -48
16 29 -69
17 29 -48
18 29 -52
19 29 -46
20 29 -51
21 29 -54
22 29 -47
23 29 -51
24 29 -60
25 29 -57
26 29 -40
27 29 -51
28 29 -50
29 29 -52
30 29 -64
31 29 -52

0 30 -46
1 30 -41
2 30 -47
3 30 -43
4 30 -46
5 30 -45
6 30 -48
7 30 -46
8 30 -40
9 30 -48
10 30 -43
11 30 -43
12 30 -42
13 30 -58
14 30 -46
15 30 -43
16 30 -53
17 30 -43
18 30 -46
19 30 -58
20 30 -42
21 30 -43
22 30 -43
23 30 -48
24 30 -40
25 30 -46
26 30 -48
27 30 -45
28 30 -46
29 30 -43
30 30 -47
31 30 -41

0 31 -58
1 31 -49
2 31 -50
3 31 -41
4 31 -43
5 31 -51
6 31 -40
7 31 -48
8 31 -43
9 31 -45
10 31 -45
11 31 -50
12 31 -42
13 31 -41
14 31 -45
15 31 -60
16 31 -43
17 31 -60
18 31 -45
19 31 -41
20 31 -42
21 31 -50
22 31 -45
23 31 -45
24 31 -43
25 31 -48
26 31 -40
27 31 -51
28 31 -43
29 31 -41
30 31 -50
31 31 -49

0 32 -39
1 32 -39
2 32 -47
3 32 -50
4 32 -43
5 32 -46
6 32 -50
7 32 -51
8 32 -53
9 32 -49
10 32 -45
11 32 -46
12 32 -53
13 32 -57
14 32 -46
15 32 -47
16 32 -42
17 32 -47
18 32 -46
19 32 -57
20 32 -53
21 32 -46
22 32 -45
23 32 -49
24 32 -53
25 32 -51
26 32 -50
27 32 -46
28 32 -43
29 32 -50
30 32 -47
31 32 -39

0 33 -42
1 33 -45
2 33 -43
3 33 -67
4 33 -40
5 33 -46
6 33 -57
7 33 -55
8 33 -45
9 33 -52
10 33 -56
11 33 -50
12 33 -49
13 33 -47
14 33 -59
15 33 -51
16 33 -77
17 33 -51
18 33 -59
19 33 -47
20 33 -49
21 33 -50
22 33 -56
23 33 -52
24 33 -45
25 33 -55
26 33 -57
27 33 -46
28 33 -40
29 33 -67
30 33 -43
31 33 -45

0 34 -43
1 34 -49
2 34 -44
3 34 -48
4 34 -43
5 34 -42
6 34 -39
7 34 -49
8 34 -51
9 34 -44
10 34 -52
11 34 -50
12 34 -40
13 34 -75
14 34 -39
15 34 -43
16 34 -46
17 34 -43
18 34 -39
19 34 -75
20 34 -40
21 34 -50
22 34 -52
23 34 -44
24 34 -51
25 34 -49
26 34 -39
27 34 -42
28 34 -43
29 34 -48
30 34 -44
31 34 -49

0 35 -48
1 35 -72
2 35 -40
3 35 -52
4 35 -42
5 35 -49
6 35 -48
7 35 -44
8 35 -53
9 35 -49
10 35 -48
11 35 -49
12 35 -60
13 35 -49
14 35 -46
15 35 -45
16 35 -63
17 35 -45
18 35 -46
19 35 -49
20 35 -60
21 35 -49
22 35 -48
23 35 -49
24 35 -53
25 35 -44
26 35 -48
27 35 -49
28 35 -42
29 35 -52
30 35 -40
31 35 -72

0 36 -54
1 36 -46
2 36 -49
3 36 -45
4 36 -42
5 36 -47
6 36 -43
7 36 -45
8 36 -41
9 36 -51
10 36 -49
11 36 -46
12 36 -49
13 36 -42
14 36 -42
15 36 -51
16 36 -54
17 36 -51
18 36 -42
19 36 -42
20 36 -49
21 36 -46
22 36 -49
23 36 -51
24 36 -41
25 36 -45
26 36 -43
27 36 -47
28 36 -42
29 36 -45
30 36 -49
31 36 -46

0 37 -59
1 37 -62
2 37 -45
3 37 -43
4 37 -46
5 37 -41
6 37 -39
7 37 -50
8 37 -45
9 37 -46
10 37 -46
11 37 -40
12 37 -46
13 37 -42
14 37 -40
15 37 -46
16 37 -45
17 37 -46
18 37 -40
19 37 -42
20 37 -46
21 37 -40
22 37 -46
23 37 -46
24 37 -45
25 37 -50
26 37 -39
27 37 -41
28 37 -46
29 37 -43
30 37 -45
31 37 -62

0 38 -63
1 38 -45
2 38 -50
3 38 -68
4 38 -58
5 38 -55
6 38 -51
7 38 -49
8 38 -45
9 38 -45
10 38 -64
11 38 -44
12 38 -42
13 38 -47
14 38 -45
15 38 -46
16 38 -46
17 38 -46
18 38 -45
19 38 -47
20 38 -42
21 38 -44
22 38 -64
23 38 -45
24 38 -45
25 38 -49
26 38 -51
27 38 -55
28 38 -58
29 38 -68
30 38 -50
31 38 -45

0 39 -42
1 39 -44
2 39 -44
3 39 -46
4 39 -46
5 39 -42
6 39 -41
7 39 -50
8 39 -57
9 39 -49
10 39 -44
11 39 -43
12 39 -40
13 39 -48
14 39 -48
15 39 -57
16 39 -39
17 39 -57
18 39 -48
19 39 -48
20 39 -40
21 39 -43
22 39 -44
23 39 -49
24 39 -57
25 39 -50
26 39 -41
27 39 -42
28 39 -46
29 39 -46
30 39 -44
31 39 -44

0 40 -44
1 40 -47
2 40 -59
3 40 -59
4 40 -52
5 40 -46
6 40 -38
7 40 -48
8 40 -51
9 40 -44
10 40 -47
11 40 -43
12 40 -53
13 40 -73
14 40 -45
15 40 -47
16 40 -116
17 40 -47
18 40 -45
19 40 -73
20 40 -53
21 40 -43
22 40 -47
23 40 -44
24 40 -51
25 40 -48
26 40 -38
27 40 -46
28 40 -52
29 40 -59
30 40 -59
31 40 -47

0 41 -42
1 41 -44
2 41 -47
3 41 -41
4 41 -51
5 41 -40
6 41 -39
7 41 -42
8 41 -50
9 41 -47
10 41 -47
11 41 -51
12 41 -48
13 41 -49
14 41 -57
15 41 -63
16 41 -43
17 41 -63
18 41 -57
19 41 -49
20 41 -48
21 41 -51
22 41 -47
23 41 -47
24 41 -50
25 41 -42
26 41 -39
27 41 -40
28 41 -51
29 41 -41
30 41 -47
31 41 -44

0 42 -44
1 42 -64
2 42 -52
3 42 -50
4 42 -43
5 42 -48
6 42 -51
7 42 -45
8 42 -43
9 42 -42
10 42 -50
11 42 -40
12 42 -56
13 42 -45
14 42 -45
15 42 -48
16 42 -65
17 42 -48
18 42 -45
19 42 -45
20 42 -56
21 42 -40
22 42 -50
23 42 -42
24 42 -43
25 42 -45
26 42 -51
27 42 -48
28 42 -43
29 42 -50
30 42 -52
31 42 -64

0 43 -42
1 43 -45
2 43 -54
3 43 -39
4 43 -47
5 43 -45
6 43 -53
7 43 -38
8 43 -42
9 43 -51
10 43 -38
11 43 -45
12 43 -46
13 43 -50
14 43 -47
15 43 -41
16 43 -39
17 43 -41
18 43 -47
19 43 -50
20 43 -46
21 43 -45
22 43 -38
23 43 -51
24 43 -42
25 43 -38
26 43 -53
27 43 -45
28 43 -47
29 43 -39
30 43 -54
31 43 -45

0 44 33
1 44 33
2 44 34
3 44 34
4 44 34
5 44 35
6 44 36
7 44 37
8 44 39
9 44 42
10 44 46
11 44 55
12 44 54
13 44 44
14 44 40
15 44 38
16 44 37
17 44 38
18 44 40
19 44 44
20 44 54
21 44 55
22 44 46
23 44 42
24 44 39
25 44 37
26 44 36
27 44 35
28 44 34
29 44 34
30 44 34
31 44 33

0 45 40
1 45 40
2 45 40
3 45 40
4 45 41
5 45 41
6 45 42
7 45 44
8 45 45
9 45 48
10 45 52
11 45 61
12 45 60
13 45 51
14 45 46
15 45 44
16 45 43
17 45 44
18 45 46
19 45 51
20 45 60
21 45 61
22 45 52
23 45 48
24 45 45
25 45 44
26 45 42
27 45 41
28 45 41
29 45 40
30 45 40
31 45 40

0 46 -51
1 46 -43
2 46 -47
3 46 -44
4 46 -50
5 46 -44
6 46 -44
7 46 -46
8 46 -45
9 46 -57
10 46 -49
11 46 -39
12 46 -49
13 46 -61
14 46 -43
15 46 -37
16 46 -51
17 46 -37
18 46 -43
19 46 -61
20 46 -49
21 46 -39
22 46 -49
23 46 -57
24 46 -45
25 46 -46
26 46 -44
27 46 -44
28 46 -50
29 46 -44
30 46 -47
31 46 -43

0 47 -46
1 47 -44
2 47 -47
3 47 -45
4 47 -44
5 47 -47
6 47 -40
7 47 -51
8 47 -44
9 47 -43
10 47 -71
11 47 -44
12 47 -46
13 47 -45
14 47 -42
15 47 -40
16 47 -35
17 47 -40
18 47 -42
19 47 -45
20 47 -46
21 47 -44
22 47 -71
23 47 -43
24 47 -44
25 47 -51
26 47 -40
27 47 -47
28 47 -44
29 47 -45
30 47 -47
31 47 -44

0 48 -47
1 48 -44
2 48 -70
3 48 -44
4 48 -46
5 48 -59
6 48 -40
7 48 -41
8 48 -62
9 48 -43
10 48 -53
11 48 -52
12 48 -43
13 48 -48
14 48 -58
15 48 -44
16 48 -47
17 48 -44
18 48 -58
19 48 -48
20 48 -43
21 48 -52
22 48 -53
23 48 -43
24 48 -62
25 48 -41
26 48 -40
27 48 -59
28 48 -46
29 48 -44
30 48 -70
31 48 -44

0 49 -50
1 49 -53
2 49 -43
3 49 -42
4 49 -46
5 49 -45
6 49 -40
7 49 -44
8 49 -41
9 49 -53
10 49 -49
11 49 -46
12 49 -44
13 49 -60
14 49 -49
15 49 -41
16 49 -43
17 49 -41
18 49 -49
19 49 -60
20 49 -44
21 49 -46
22 49 -49
23 49 -53
24 49 -41
25 49 -44
26 49 -40
27 49 -45
28 49 -46
29 49 -42
30 49 -43
31 49 -53

0 50 -53
1 50 -45
2 50 -45
3 50 -54
4 50 -40
5 50 -42
6 50 -41
7 50 -42
8 50 -44
9 50 -57
10 50 -47
11 50 -44
12 50 -41
13 50 -45
14 50 -51
15 50 -51
16 50 -43
17 50 -51
18 50 -51
19 50 -45
20 50 -41
21 50 -44
22 50 -47
23 50 -57
24 50 -44
25 50 -42
26 50 -41
27 50 -42
28 50 -40
29 50 -54
30 50 -45
31 50 -45

0 51 -58
1 51 -54
2 51 -53
3 51 -44
4 51 -47
5 51 -43
6 51 -44
7 51 -42
8 51 -42
9 51 -48
10 51 -42
11 51 -52
12 51 -47
13 51 -46
14 51 -42
15 51 -47
16 51 -58
17 51 -47
18 51 -42
19 51 -46
20 51 -47
21 51 -52
22 51 -42
23 51 -48
24 51 -42
25 51 -42
26 51 -44
27 51 -43
28 51 -47
29 51 -44
30 51 -53
31 51 -54

0 52 -43
1 52 -49
2 52 -57
3 52 -68
4 52 -42
5 52 -47
6 52 -46
7 52 -51
8 52 -43
9 52 -62
10 52 -45
11 52 -47
12 52 -56
13 52 -50
14 52 -51
15 52 -59
16 52 -66
17 52 -59
18 52 -51
19 52 -50
20 52 -56
21 52 -47
22 52 -45
23 52 -62
24 52 -43
25 52 -51
26 52 -46
27 52 -47
28 52 -42
29 52 -68
30 52 -57
31 52 -49

0 53 -49
1 53 -54
2 53 -54
3 53 -44
4 53 -41
5 53 -50
6 53 -54
7 53 -54
8 53 -47
9 53 -44
10 53 -39
11 53 -59
12 53 -39
13 53 -47
14 53 -46
15 53 -42
16 53 -38
17 53 -42
18 53 -46
19 53 -47
20 53 -39
21 53 -59
22 53 -39
23 53 -44
24 53 -47
25 53 -54
26 53 -54
27 53 -50
28 53 -41
29 53 -44
30 53 -54
31 53 -54

0 54 -59
1 54 -49
2 54 -45
3 54 -45
4 54 -46
5 54 -41
6 54 -49
7 54 -46
8 54 -49
9 54 -52
10 54 -43
11 54 -54
12 54 -46
13 54 -47
14 54 -46
15 54 -43
16 54 -41
17 54 -43
18 54 -46
19 54 -47
20 54 -46
21 54 -54
22 54 -43
23 54 -52
24 54 -49
25 54 -46
26 54 -49
27 54 -41
28 54 -46
29 54 -45
30 54 -45
31 54 -49

0 55 -46
1 55 -43
2 55 -42
3 55 -47
4 55 -48
5 55 -53
6 55 -51
7 55 -60
8 55 -42
9 55 -46
10 55 -45
11 55 -44
12 55 -54
13 55 -45
14 55 -41
15 55 -47
16 55 -52
17 55 -47
18 55 -41
19 55 -45
20 55 -54
21 55 -44
22 55 -45
23 55 -46
24 55 -42
25 55 -60
26 55 -51
27 55 -53
28 55 -48
29 55 -47
30 55 -42
31 55 -43

0 56 -38
1 56 -44
2 56 -43
3 56 -48
4 56 -45
5 56 -56
6 56 -53
7 56 -39
8 56 -48
9 56 -47
10 56 -44
11 56 -44
12 56 -47
13 56 -49
14 56 -45
15 56 -60
16 56 -50
17 56 -60
18 56 -45
19 56 -49
20 56 -47
21 56 -44
22 56 -44
23 56 -47
24 56 -48
25 56 -39
26 56 -53
27 56 -56
28 56 -45
29 56 -48
30 56 -43
31 56 -44

0 57 -40
1 57 -51
2 57 -54
3 57 -40
4 57 -46
5 57 -49
6 57 -54
7 57 -55
8 57 -44
9 57 -64
10 57 -43
11 57 -44
12 57 -47
13 57 -45
14 57 -45
15 57 -46
16 57 101
17 57 -46
18 57 -45
19 57 -45
20 57 -47
21 57 -44
22 57 -43
23 57 -64
24 57 -44
25 57 -55
26 57 -54
27 57 -49
28 57 -46
29 57 -40
30 57 -54
31 57 -51
\end{filecontents*}
%
\documentclass[paper=a4]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{width=8.6cm,height=8.6cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    hide axis = true,
    view={0}{90},
  ]
    \addplot3[
      surf,
      mesh/ordering=y varies,
    ] file {RDM.dat};
  \end{axis}
  \draw (0,0) rectangle (7,7);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Sorry, the example is not minimal in the narrower sense.

Comment: Do you mean something like [Drawing heatmaps using TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44868)?

Comment: 'Something like' is correct. This might be a solution (I did not think of a table, but in effect it is quite similar), but I am afraid that the possible size of my data matrix may be problematic: each dimension can reach the order of 100 and the color code should have at least 20 steps.

Comment: Sigh! Yes, this link might really be a solution. I will have a closer look at it and try to use only the inner part of the graph (as I do not need the axes and so on). Many thanks for the hint! I am really anxious if I get this to a working solution.

Comment: `hide axis=true` as an option to the `axis` environment should remove the axis.

Comment: Thanks, works fine. At this moment there only seems to be an issue with my successless approach to read the file (with coordinates {} it already works). I will give it a chance and be back tomorrow.

Comment: To specify the size of the plot without the labels, use `scale only axis`. To fix the issue with the colours, set `interp=flat corner`.

Comment: Thus easy? Great! I added `scale only axis` and `shader=flat corner` and it works like a charm. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

with PSTricks. Run it with

```
latex <file>
dvips <file>
ps2pdf -dNOSAFER <file>.ps
```

The data must be saved in an external file as PostScript array of arrays:

```
/contourdata[[
x y z
...
][
x y z
...
]] def
```

You'll find the complete file [here](http://perce.de/pub/contourN.data)

You can modify the radius of the dots

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
%
\begin{document}
\psset{unit=0.25cm}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(32,57)
\pstContour[colored,radius=3pt]{contourN.data}
\end{pspicture}

\medskip
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(32,57)
\pstContour[radius=3pt]{contourN.data}
\end{pspicture}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, Herbert, for this pstricks solution. But I changed many years ago from pstricks to TikZ and do not want to mix these tools as long as I get a working solution with TikZ.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a full solution but a proof of concept using TikZ and `foreach`.
I dropped the first two columns of your data and transformed the third one to a list of values. The 'value to color' function can be adjusted.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \edef\s{32} % the number of columns
  \edef\data{-71, -44, -42, -45, -43, -51, -53, -46, -40, -51, -35, -42, -65, -51, -43, -43, -48, -43, -43, -51, -65, -42, -35, -51, -40, -46, -53, -51, -43, -45, -42, -44, -44, -49, -45, -45, -43, -50, -43, -51, -44, -43, -41, -52, -43, -64, -46, -50, -40, -50, -46, -64, -43, -52, -41, -43, -44, -51, -43, -50, -43, -45, -45, -49, -65, -44, -40, -53, -53, -48, -43, -44, -55, -43, -45, -65, -46, -37, -39, -38, -50, -38, -39, -37, -46, -65, -45, -43, -55, -44, -43, -48, -53, -53, -40, -44, -40, -43, -42, -50, -41, -54, -44, -49, -40, -42, -45, -37, -49, -43, -49, -41, -57, -41, -49, -43, -49, -37, -45, -42, -40, -49, -44, -54, -41, -50, -42, -43, -41, -71, -43, -49, -49, -58, -47, -52, -39, -51, -51, -53, -45, -60, -43, -46, -39, -46, -43, -60, -45, -53, -51, -51, -39, -52, -47, -58, -49, -49, -43, -71, -45, -51, -49, -43, -45, -37, -48, -48, -41, -48, -45, -42, -46, -48, -51, -47, -40, -47, -51, -48, -46, -42, -45, -48, -41, -48, -48, -37, -45, -43, -49, -51, -46, -52, -49, -39, -47, -54, -47, -43, -48, -39, -43, -51, -40, -38, -53, -55, -65, -55, -53, -38, -40, -51, -43, -39, -48, -43, -47, -54, -47, -39, -49, -52, -54, -46, -55, -47, -44, -53, -40, -41, -43, -38, -45, -60, -40, -46, -44, -44, -45, -44, -44, -46, -40, -60, -45, -38, -43, -41, -40, -53, -44, -47, -55, -46, -52, -48, -42, -46, -47, -48, -42, -40, -53, -41, -40, -53, -48, -44, -50, -51, -50, -51, -50, -44, -48, -53, -40, -41, -53, -40, -42, -48, -47, -46, -42, -48, -65, -53, -45, -67, -45, -39, -50, -43, -53, -61, -44, -46, -44, -49, -47, -49, -39, -49, -47, -49, -44, -46, -44, -61, -53, -43, -50, -39, -45, -67, -45, -53, -42, -48, -46, -42, -51, -43, -44, -54, -41, -55, -41, -39, -47, -50, -42, -54, -47, -54, -42, -50, -47, -39, -41, -55, -41, -54, -44, -43, -51, -42, -46, -48, -48, -48, -43, -41, -47, -48, -52, -49, -43, -50, -43, -48, -48, -50, -46, -45, -60, -45, -46, -50, -48, -48, -43, -50, -43, -49, -52, -48, -47, -41, -43, -48, -45, -44, -38, -39, -42, -44, -51, -41, -50, -40, -58, -53, -46, -46, -39, -56, -42, -56, -39, -46, -46, -53, -58, -40, -50, -41, -51, -44, -42, -39, -38, -44, -66, -43, -52, -55, -56, -60, -51, -43, -42, -52, -41, -49, -40, -51, -47, -46, -65, -46, -47, -51, -40, -49, -41, -52, -42, -43, -51, -60, -56, -55, -52, -43, -49, -39, -42, -62, -44, -47, -40, -47, -45, -41, -45, -50, -45, -43, -45, -51, -82, -51, -45, -43, -45, -50, -45, -41, -45, -47, -40, -47, -44, -62, -42, -39, -45, -41, -55, -44, -41, -52, -43, -46, -49, -47, -51, -46, -49, -46, -44, -50, -65, -50, -44, -46, -49, -46, -51, -47, -49, -46, -43, -52, -41, -44, -55, -41, -63, -58, -51, -55, -47, -48, -43, -50, -46, -45, -46, -52, -50, -50, -50, -41, -45, -41, -50, -50, -50, -52, -46, -45, -46, -50, -43, -48, -47, -55, -51, -58, -44, -44, -44, -45, -62, -55, -48, -47, -46, -44, -51, -44, -48, -41, -50, -41, -56, -41, -50, -41, -48, -44, -51, -44, -46, -47, -48, -55, -62, -45, -44, -44, -53, -47, -49, -48, -51, -60, -53, -51, -42, -43, -52, -46, -51, -40, -44, -61, -51, -61, -44, -40, -51, -46, -52, -43, -42, -51, -53, -60, -51, -48, -49, -47, -43, -43, -48, -48, -39, -48, -51, -49, -47, -46, -55, -56, -52, -50, -44, -48, -47, -48, -44, -50, -52, -56, -55, -46, -47, -49, -51, -48, -39, -48, -48, -43, -51, -50, -45, -49, -45, -53, -58, -48, -48, -39, -48, -60, -48, -60, -45, -45, -47, -45, -45, -60, -48, -60, -48, -39, -48, -48, -58, -53, -45, -49, -45, -50, -38, -45, -47, -54, -46, -47, -44, -46, -44, -48, -41, -43, -54, -42, -49, -55, -65, -55, -49, -42, -54, -43, -41, -48, -44, -46, -44, -47, -46, -54, -47, -45, -51, -47, -54, -49, -44, -44, -50, -48, -61, -49, -42, -46, -46, -46, -51, -41, -71, -41, -51, -46, -46, -46, -42, -49, -61, -48, -50, -44, -44, -49, -54, -47, -44, -49, -40, -44, -48, -50, -43, -44, -44, -46, -49, -46, -43, -47, -40, -50, -47, -50, -40, -47, -43, -46, -49, -46, -44, -44, -43, -50, -48, -44, -40, -49, -73, -52, -41, -49, -47, -61, -54, -55, -49, -39, -39, -66, -47, -48, -49, -52, -67, -52, -49, -48, -47, -66, -39, -39, -49, -55, -54, -61, -47, -49, -41, -52, -48, -54, -42, -46, -41, -45, -44, -40, -45, -53, -43, -39, -37, -53, -46, -50, -57, -50, -46, -53, -37, -39, -43, -53, -45, -40, -44, -45, -41, -46, -42, -54, -48, -44, -51, -50, -42, -49, -49, -44, -43, -54, -48, -50, -46, -48, -44, -52, -58, -52, -44, -48, -46, -50, -48, -54, -43, -44, -49, -49, -42, -50, -51, -44, -56, -46, -50, -47, -46, -51, -50, -52, -41, -57, -49, -50, -47, -51, -43, -51, -40, -51, -43, -51, -47, -50, -49, -57, -41, -52, -50, -51, -46, -47, -50, -46, -59, -44, -49, -56, -54, -43, -49, -50, -54, -48, -39, -40, -43, -40, -39, -45, -47, -45, -39, -40, -43, -40, -39, -48, -54, -50, -49, -43, -54, -56, -49, -44, -53, -52, -64, -52, -50, -51, -40, -57, -60, -51, -47, -54, -51, -46, -52, -48, -69, -48, -52, -46, -51, -54, -47, -51, -60, -57, -40, -51, -50, -52, -64, -52, -46, -41, -47, -43, -46, -45, -48, -46, -40, -48, -43, -43, -42, -58, -46, -43, -53, -43, -46, -58, -42, -43, -43, -48, -40, -46, -48, -45, -46, -43, -47, -41, -58, -49, -50, -41, -43, -51, -40, -48, -43, -45, -45, -50, -42, -41, -45, -60, -43, -60, -45, -41, -42, -50, -45, -45, -43, -48, -40, -51, -43, -41, -50, -49, -39, -39, -47, -50, -43, -46, -50, -51, -53, -49, -45, -46, -53, -57, -46, -47, -42, -47, -46, -57, -53, -46, -45, -49, -53, -51, -50, -46, -43, -50, -47, -39, -42, -45, -43, -67, -40, -46, -57, -55, -45, -52, -56, -50, -49, -47, -59, -51, -77, -51, -59, -47, -49, -50, -56, -52, -45, -55, -57, -46, -40, -67, -43, -45, -43, -49, -44, -48, -43, -42, -39, -49, -51, -44, -52, -50, -40, -75, -39, -43, -46, -43, -39, -75, -40, -50, -52, -44, -51, -49, -39, -42, -43, -48, -44, -49, -48, -72, -40, -52, -42, -49, -48, -44, -53, -49, -48, -49, -60, -49, -46, -45, -63, -45, -46, -49, -60, -49, -48, -49, -53, -44, -48, -49, -42, -52, -40, -72, -54, -46, -49, -45, -42, -47, -43, -45, -41, -51, -49, -46, -49, -42, -42, -51, -54, -51, -42, -42, -49, -46, -49, -51, -41, -45, -43, -47, -42, -45, -49, -46, -59, -62, -45, -43, -46, -41, -39, -50, -45, -46, -46, -40, -46, -42, -40, -46, -45, -46, -40, -42, -46, -40, -46, -46, -45, -50, -39, -41, -46, -43, -45, -62, -63, -45, -50, -68, -58, -55, -51, -49, -45, -45, -64, -44, -42, -47, -45, -46, -46, -46, -45, -47, -42, -44, -64, -45, -45, -49, -51, -55, -58, -68, -50, -45, -42, -44, -44, -46, -46, -42, -41, -50, -57, -49, -44, -43, -40, -48, -48, -57, -39, -57, -48, -48, -40, -43, -44, -49, -57, -50, -41, -42, -46, -46, -44, -44, -44, -47, -59, -59, -52, -46, -38, -48, -51, -44, -47, -43, -53, -73, -45, -47, -116, -47, -45, -73, -53, -43, -47, -44, -51, -48, -38, -46, -52, -59, -59, -47, -42, -44, -47, -41, -51, -40, -39, -42, -50, -47, -47, -51, -48, -49, -57, -63, -43, -63, -57, -49, -48, -51, -47, -47, -50, -42, -39, -40, -51, -41, -47, -44, -44, -64, -52, -50, -43, -48, -51, -45, -43, -42, -50, -40, -56, -45, -45, -48, -65, -48, -45, -45, -56, -40, -50, -42, -43, -45, -51, -48, -43, -50, -52, -64, -42, -45, -54, -39, -47, -45, -53, -38, -42, -51, -38, -45, -46, -50, -47, -41, -39, -41, -47, -50, -46, -45, -38, -51, -42, -38, -53, -45, -47, -39, -54, -45, 33, 33, 34, 34, 34, 35, 36, 37, 39, 42, 46, 55, 54, 44, 40, 38, 37, 38, 40, 44, 54, 55, 46, 42, 39, 37, 36, 35, 34, 34, 34, 33, 40, 40, 40, 40, 41, 41, 42, 44, 45, 48, 52, 61, 60, 51, 46, 44, 43, 44, 46, 51, 60, 61, 52, 48, 45, 44, 42, 41, 41, 40, 40, 40, -51, -43, -47, -44, -50, -44, -44, -46, -45, -57, -49, -39, -49, -61, -43, -37, -51, -37, -43, -61, -49, -39, -49, -57, -45, -46, -44, -44, -50, -44, -47, -43, -46, -44, -47, -45, -44, -47, -40, -51, -44, -43, -71, -44, -46, -45, -42, -40, -35, -40, -42, -45, -46, -44, -71, -43, -44, -51, -40, -47, -44, -45, -47, -44, -47, -44, -70, -44, -46, -59, -40, -41, -62, -43, -53, -52, -43, -48, -58, -44, -47, -44, -58, -48, -43, -52, -53, -43, -62, -41, -40, -59, -46, -44, -70, -44, -50, -53, -43, -42, -46, -45, -40, -44, -41, -53, -49, -46, -44, -60, -49, -41, -43, -41, -49, -60, -44, -46, -49, -53, -41, -44, -40, -45, -46, -42, -43, -53, -53, -45, -45, -54, -40, -42, -41, -42, -44, -57, -47, -44, -41, -45, -51, -51, -43, -51, -51, -45, -41, -44, -47, -57, -44, -42, -41, -42, -40, -54, -45, -45, -58, -54, -53, -44, -47, -43, -44, -42, -42, -48, -42, -52, -47, -46, -42, -47, -58, -47, -42, -46, -47, -52, -42, -48, -42, -42, -44, -43, -47, -44, -53, -54, -43, -49, -57, -68, -42, -47, -46, -51, -43, -62, -45, -47, -56, -50, -51, -59, -66, -59, -51, -50, -56, -47, -45, -62, -43, -51, -46, -47, -42, -68, -57, -49, -49, -54, -54, -44, -41, -50, -54, -54, -47, -44, -39, -59, -39, -47, -46, -42, -38, -42, -46, -47, -39, -59, -39, -44, -47, -54, -54, -50, -41, -44, -54, -54, -59, -49, -45, -45, -46, -41, -49, -46, -49, -52, -43, -54, -46, -47, -46, -43, -41, -43, -46, -47, -46, -54, -43, -52, -49, -46, -49, -41, -46, -45, -45, -49, -46, -43, -42, -47, -48, -53, -51, -60, -42, -46, -45, -44, -54, -45, -41, -47, -52, -47, -41, -45, -54, -44, -45, -46, -42, -60, -51, -53, -48, -47, -42, -43, -38, -44, -43, -48, -45, -56, -53, -39, -48, -47, -44, -44, -47, -49, -45, -60, -50, -60, -45, -49, -47, -44, -44, -47, -48, -39, -53, -56, -45, -48, -43, -44, -40, -51, -54, -40, -46, -49, -54, -55, -44, -64, -43, -44, -47, -45, -45, -46, 101, -46, -45, -45, -47, -44, -43, -64, -44, -55, -54, -49, -46, -40, -54, -51}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.3]
    \foreach[count=\n, evaluate={\c=\v/2.4+50;\i = int(mod(\n-1,\s));\j = div(\n-1,\s)}]
      \v in \data
      \fill[red!\c!yellow] (\i,\j) rectangle +(1,1);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]