# How to use xcolor to color a pgfplot

Tags: color, pgfplotstable

How do I use xcolor to color a specific cell from a table in pgfplots? Is xcolor the best tool to use here? I'm trying to loop over a list of colors and color the cells in the column individually.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable,filecontents}
\RequirePackage{listofitems}
\usepackage{}

\begin{filecontents*}{test.csv}
    ColA, ColB, ColC
    0.17, 0.91, 0.67
    0.15, 0.17, 0.92
    0.48, 0.1, 0.28
\end{filecontents*}




\begin{document}
    \pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=comma,
    ]{test.csv}
    \def\mylistOne{green, blue, orange}
    \readlist*\mylistTwo{\mylistOne}
    \newcounter{myCounter}
    \setcounter{myCounter}{-1}
    \foreachitem\x\in\mylistTwo[]{
        \stepcounter{myCounter}
        \pgfplotstableset{
            every row \themyCounter column 1/.style={
                \cellcolor{\x}
        }
    }
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: xcolor is a package, which you can load to access some predefined colors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is

- `colortbl` (it provides `\cellcolor` and `\rowcolor`).
- an extra instruction such that `pgfplotstable` knows that you want to modify the content of the current cell (as opposed to loading some option). This is done by modifying `@cell content` inside of `every row 2 column 1/.style` .
- A fix to the expansion: the instruction `every row \themyCounter column 1` expands to something like `every row 3column 1`, i.e. you need add `\space` (according to a general rule of how TeX gobbles spaces after macro names).
- A fix to the expansion inside of the loop: writing `\x` inside of a style fails because TeX inserts the name `\x` instead of its value -- and the name becomes meaningless once the loop iteration is done. To solve this, we need control over expansion (compare [Where do I start LaTeX programming?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12668/where-do-i-start-latex-programming/27589#27589))

Here is a potential solution:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable,filecontents}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{filecontents*}{test.csv}
    ColA, ColB, ColC
    0.17, 0.91, 0.67
    0.15, 0.17, 0.92
    0.48, 0.1, 0.28
\end{filecontents*}



\begin{document}
    \newcounter{myCounter}
    \setcounter{myCounter}{-1}

    % extracted this as separate macro such that I can get rid of the
    % '\x' macro below
    \def\kevinassigncolor#1{%
        \pgfplotstableset{
            every row \themyCounter\space column 1/.style={
                postproc cell content/.style={
                    @cell content/.add={\cellcolor{#1}}{}%
                },%
            },
        }%
    }%


    \pgfplotsforeachungrouped\x in{green,blue,orange}{%
        \stepcounter{myCounter}%
        % the \expandafter is a trick to ensure that \kevinassigncolor
        % does not see the '\x':
        % we must not write \cellcolor{\x} into a style because the
        % meaning of \x will be lost as soon as we left this loop
        % iteration!
        % \expandafter inserts the _value_ of \x rather than '\x':
        \expandafter\kevinassigncolor\expandafter{\x}%
    }
    \pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=comma,
    ]{test.csv}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that I substituted `\foreachitem` by `\pgfplotsforeachungrouped`, but only because I do not have package `listofitems` at hand.

See also the related application [Drawing heatmaps using TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44868/drawing-heatmaps-using-tikz)

Comment: How would I handle expansion control if I wanted to pass the column index into \kevinassigncolor as well?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out! As easy as adding #2 to the \kevinassigncolor!