# Heatmap in Table from green to yellow to red using pgfplots/pgfplotstable

Tags: tables, pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I am currently working my way through one error to another. What I want to create:

[image]

So in essence a table with color coded cells that gradually fade from red to yellow to dark green. Ideally, in each row the highest value should be red while the lowest value is dark green.

As I was searching for answers I found out that the pgfplot packages is very useful but I am overwhelmed with the amount of code/syntax I do not understand. I found this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/338937/274228 and was already struggling to change the color range to what I want (green -> yellow -> red).

Thanks for any help in advance. If I have to provide more details, please let me know. The use of pgfplots is not mandatory but after pursuing an approach like https://tikz.net/heatmap/ (because of the readability) I figured this lacks needed options for customization. Some comments in the code about what does what would be also highly appreciated!

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/440228/heatmap-in-table?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in the end I helped myself using excel and https://www.tablesgenerator.com/.

Essentially what you can do is create the table using excel, use dependent formatting for the desired color scheme. In the example above you should do this for each row separately.

After that you have a table that should look like the above (or what you want). Then use https://www.tablesgenerator.com/ to copy&paste the table, make last adjustments and generate the latex code.

Saved myself a lot of time and probably is the easiest way to get good looking heatmaps, at least for me.