# Colorize column based on cell values, automatically detecting min and max, ignoring empty cells

Tags: conditionals, scaling, automatic, empty

Extending on the brilliant (!!!) solution provided by [muzimuzhi Z](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/79060/muzimuzhi-z) here:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/543860/305561,:

1. could we have a capability to ignore empty/non-numeric cells in a column, and leave them with the default white background?
   (Having empty cells in the latex answer/code provided leads to compilation error, something e.g. `"Package color Error: Argument 1.01212 not in range [0,1]."`, as the empty cells gets treated as a value=0).

*A. One solution that works is to mark every empty cell as `\multicolumn{1}{l}{}` or a cell to be ignored as `\multicolumn{1}{l}{text to be ignored}`. But this is tedious, and I wonder if there is a latex script to ignore empty/non-numeric cells automatically.*

2. could we determine min and max values in a column automatically to determine color scaling? i.e. instead of explicitly stating  `P{-0.0015}{0.003}` as in the answer provided in the link above, i.e. could we have an automatic `P{\auto_evaluated_min_in_column}{\auto_evaluated_max_in_column}`?

Comment: Answer to question 1 is quite simple: just wrap the definition of `\colorfromval` (except for the last line `\tablenum[#3]{#4}`) in `\ifstrempty{#4}{}{<original definition>}`. (I just added a revised example in my [previous answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/543860/79060).) As for question 2, first a second compilation is required if still using `tabular` environment, then currently I don't know how to get a distinct naming per `P` column (to store the min/max value to aux file). Maybe it's easier with `tabularray`, a recent tabular package.