# Conditional coloring in LaTeX

Tags: formatting, color, conditionals

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parametrize shading in table through TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42444/parametrize-shading-in-table-through-tikz)

Is there any package that provide conditional coloring in LaTeX ?

I would like to reproduce what Excel does with its conditional formatting feature, e.g. :

[image]

In my example I would like to specify two colors (here red and blue) and format a `tabular`environment such that cells background-color varies linearly between the two specified colors depending on the max/min value found in the `tabular`.

Comment: What sort of thing do you want to colour?  The general answer is "yes" but an actual implementation might depend on what format the data is in so if you could add a compileable document with that data and explain what colouring you would like to see, that will help people provide the most help.

Comment: Thanks for helping me improving my post. I edited to make it more specific.

Comment: That's better.  Does the question that Jake links to help you?