# Heatmap Table with Latex and Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parametrize shading in table through TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42444/parametrize-shading-in-table-through-tikz)
>   [Drawing heatmaps using TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44868/drawing-heatmaps-using-tikz)

is there a way to generate heatmap like tables in LaTeX, for example with `tikz`? I have a really huge table with values like that in figure [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyrjL.jpg) which is quite confusing and to get a better overview such a color filling would help.

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) This question is very similar to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42444/parametrize-shading-in-table-through-tikz. Please take a look at it as the information there might help you. If so, that's great, and we'll probably close this question as a duplicate just to keep the place tidy and to help people find answers quickly. If not, please edit your question here to explain why so that people can better focus their attention to help you.

Comment: Hi lockstep, thanks! I'll take a look ;-)

Comment: Hmm ok I think this post might be answered by the other question! Thanks for helping me out ;-)

Comment: Also at least related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44868/drawing-heatmaps-using-tikz