# Open source workflow to represent a number in a table cell by its background color

Tags: tables, color, colortbl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parametrize shading in table through TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42444/parametrize-shading-in-table-through-tikz)
>   [Drawing heatmaps using TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44868/drawing-heatmaps-using-tikz)

I know this isn't strictly speaking a LaTeX question, so please move this somewhere else if you feel like it.

I find large tables of numeric values a bit hard to comprehend at a glance ... or even many. One strategy to alleviate this is to set the hue of the background color according to the value in that cell. So for values in [0, 1], 0 would be red, 0.3 might be yellow, 1 is blue etc.

Has anyone a workflow using open source tools that produces a native LaTeX table (not a picture with strange fonts or suchlike) from a CSV file (or some other format that you can easily convert to with say LibreOffice or gnumeric)?

Choosing a color from a simple gradient would be ok, too, I guess, since then you don't need some HSV→RGB conversion. Examples for this latter variant could look like this (the second isn't with numbers though, obviously):

[image: color matrix from uniplot]
[image: other example, just not with numbers]

Comment: Please take a look at the questions linked at [Heatmap Table with Latex and TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76185/heatmap-table-with-latex-and-tikz). Would those approaches work for you, or do you have more specific requirements?

Comment: @Jake That looks very much like what I wanted. Sorry I didn't find that myself. This can be closed then.

Comment: No problem! It's often quite hard to find relevant questions.