# How does one construct an abstract (n × n) empty grid of squares?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, formatting, grid-typesetting, grids

---

I would like to just create a grid like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79998/is-it-possible-to-draw-an-n-by-n-grid-with-text-in-each-cell-with-a-different-b), but without numbers or color, but I'd like to represent an *n* × *n* grid abstractly with ellipses like this:

[image]

---

Also, I need just a simple—singular—grid like that of the top left grid in the image above.

---

I know need a red line (y=x) from the lower left corner to the upper right corner.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I added the picture you linked to the question. Later, with more reputation points earned, you will be able to do it yourself. Happy TeXing! `:)`

Comment: Would you rather do this as a table or as a `tikzpicture` (since you seem to have included both tags)?

Comment: I included both tags so that the experienced answerer could choose between the easier of the two, but I would like to get a handle on tikz, so perhaps tikz is my answer.

Comment: It could be done in a `tabular`, but the fact that the rules aren't continuous would cause for some ugliness.  It's not that it's hard (once you get to grips with tabulars), it's just *ugly*.  (The `tabular` solution would potentially be more efficient, but the TikZ solution is prettier by *far*.)

Comment: I just *know* there is a good way to do this with `ytableau`; I just don't know what it is.  The attempt has uncovered several potentially useful features I could add, though.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A very basic approach using `grid`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) grid (3,3);
\draw (0,4) grid (3,7);
\draw (4,0) grid (7,3);
\draw (4,4) grid (7,7);
\foreach \i/\valor in {1/1,2/2,3/3,5/n-2,6/n-1,7/n}
  {
    \node[anchor=south] at (\i-0.5,7) {$\valor$};
    \node[anchor=east] at (0,-\i+7.5) {$\valor$};
}
\node at (3.5,1.5) {$\cdots$};
\node at (3.5,5.5) {$\cdots$};
\node at (1.5,3.5) {$\vdots$};
\node at (5.5,3.5) {$\vdots$};
\node at (3.5,3.5) {$\ddots$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With the new requirement of the edited question:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) grid (3,3);
\draw (0,4) grid (3,7);
\draw (4,0) grid (7,3);
\draw (4,4) grid (7,7);
\foreach \i/\valor in {1/1,2/2,3/3,5/n-2,6/n-1,7/n}
  {
    \node[anchor=south] at (\i-0.5,7) {$\valor$};
    \node[anchor=east] at (0,-\i+7.5) {$\valor$};
}
\node at (3.5,1.5) {$\cdots$};
\node at (3.5,5.5) {$\cdots$};
\node at (1.5,3.5) {$\vdots$};
\node at (5.5,3.5) {$\vdots$};
\node at (3.5,3.5) {$\ddots$};
\draw[red,ultra thick] (0,0) -- (7,7);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: OMG... You are amazing. Thank you! `:-)`

Comment: What if I want to put a giant slash from the lower left corner to the upper right corner in red?

Comment: @LoieBenedicte just before `\end{tikzpicture}`, you can add `\draw[red] (0,0) -- (7,7);`

Comment: Hmmm... How do you get a bold red?

Comment: @LoieBenedicte do you mean to increase the line width? If so, `\draw[red, ultra thick] (0,0) -- (7,7);` or `\draw[red,line width=4pt] (0,0) -- (7,7);` (change `4pt` to the desired value).