# Misplaced \omit. ...\w{wk} & \w{jg} & \w{cl} & \w{rn}\& \w{cl}

Tags: matrices

I am using [Qrrbrbirlbel's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79998/is-it-possible-to-draw-an-n-by-n-grid-with-text-in-each-cell-with-a-different-b) to build the confusion matrix as given  in the figure. The problem is when extend the rows and  column to 10  as given in the code it gives me the error as stated in the title. I have to draw 14*14 matrix.
Kindly help

```
      \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array,hhline}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\ccol}[1]{%
    \ifdim#1pt<.5pt\relax\else\color{white}\fi
    \edef\x{\noexpand\cellcolor[gray]{\strip@pt\dimexpr1pt-#1pt}}\x
    #1%
}
\newlength{\cellwidth}
\settowidth{\cellwidth}{0.00}
\def\jline{\\\hhline{~*{10}{|-}|}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{l*{10}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{\cellwidth}}|}
        \noalign{\gdef\w#1{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}}
        \w{} & \w{hw} & \w{bx} & \w{wk} & \w{jg} & \w{cl} & \w{rn}\& \w{cl} & \w{rn}\& \w{cl} & \w{rn}\jline
        ving & \ccol{1} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0& 0 & 0& 0 & 0\jline
        xing & 0 & \ccol{0.92} & \ccol{0.08} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0& 0 & 0\jline
        king & 0 & \ccol{0.03} & \ccol{0.97} & 0 & 0 & 0& 0 & 0& 0 & 0\jline
        ging & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ccol{1} & 0 & 0& 0 & 0& 0 & 0\jline
        ping & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ccol{1} & 0& 0 & 0& 0 & 0\jline
        ning & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ccol{1}& 0 & 0& 0 & 0\jline
        ning & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ccol{1}& 0 & 0& 0 & 0\jline
        ning & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ccol{1}& 0 & 0& 0 & 0\jline
        ning & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ccol{1}& 0 & 0& 0 & 0\jline
        ning & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ccol{1}& 0 & 0& 0 & 0\jline
        \noalign{\global\let\w\undefined}
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Start with `*{10}` not `*10`.

Comment: Thank you Daleif, i have replaced it  and now its giving this error: Misplaced \omit. ...\w{wk} & \w{jg} & \w{cl} & \w{rn}\& \w{cl}

Comment: Then update your question. I wouldn't define `\w` at that location.

Comment: Daleif, Should i update the question by replacing  *10 with *{10}  and  with new error?

Comment: You should yes,

Comment: Dear Daleif, i have updated the question.

Comment: You have `\&` (twice) instead of `&`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue is due to a typo.

Comment: What's the purpose of defining `\w` inside `\noalign` and to make it globally undefined at the end? This will overwrite any standing definition of `\w`. Thus it's much better to do `\newcommand{\w}{...}` in the preamble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem appears to be comint from the definition of `\w` ([possibly related](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69608/172926)).

The simplest fix would be to remove that definition and just manually write out the `\multicolumn` command for the first row:

```
    \begin{tabular}{l*{10}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{\cellwidth}}|}
        % \noalign{\gdef\w#1{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}}
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{hw} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{bx} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{wk} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{jg} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{cl} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{rn} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{cl} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{rn} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{cl} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{rn}\jline
        ving & \ccol{1} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0& 0 & 0& 0 & 0\jline
        xing & 0 & \ccol{0.92} & \ccol{0.08} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0& 0 & 0\jline
        king & 0 & \ccol{0.03} & \ccol{0.97} & 0 & 0 & 0& 0 & 0& 0 & 0\jline
        ging & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ccol{1} & 0 & 0& 0 & 0& 0 & 0\jline
        ping & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ccol{1} & 0& 0 & 0& 0 & 0\jline
        ning & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ccol{1}& 0 & 0& 0 & 0\jline
        ning & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ccol{1}& 0 & 0& 0 & 0\jline
        ning & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ccol{1}& 0 & 0& 0 & 0\jline
        ning & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ccol{1}& 0 & 0& 0 & 0\jline
        ning & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ccol{1}& 0 & 0& 0 & 0\jline
        % \noalign{\global\let\w\undefined}
    \end{tabular}
```

Output:

[image: output]

Comment: Thank you very much.  There is only one problem left that this in textstudio editor there are error appearing on & (highlighted with red color) and when i bring  the mouse cursor over it gives(more cols then specified). Should  i add the snapshot of it ?

Comment: Does the message go if you change `l*{10}` to `l*{11}`?

Comment: It remains the same even by replacing with 1*{11}.

Comment: It is difficult for me to tell because I don't have texstudio. Perhaps the program does not recognise the `\jline` command. Does it still compile? If so, I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Yes, It compile perfectly.. I was only worried about the warnings that are appearing on the & by highlighting with red color.