# Table cell/element color parameterization with xcolor

Tags: tables, color, shading

I have a `table` (implemented through `tabular`)  that uses the `xcolor` package to shade certain cells. The shading I'm interested is both entire cell shading (e.g. `\cellcolor{red}`) and element shading (e.g. `\color{red}`).

What I want to achieve is a function through `xcolor` (or similar package) that would allow me to implement a color of varying intensity. For example it would be nice if I could go `\color{red}{0.01}` in a cell, and the contents were only slightly red (but still almost black), or `\color{red}{1.00}` and the contents would be completely red.

How can I achieve this with both `\cellcolor{red}` and `\color{red}`?

Here's an example table that I want to achieve this in:

```
\begin{table}[!tbp]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{rrrrl}
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Sepal.Length}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Sepal.Width}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Petal.Length}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Petal.Width}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Species}\tabularnewline
\hline
   $5.1$&   $3.5$&   $1.4$&   $0.2$&   setosa\tabularnewline
   $4.9$&\cellcolor{red}   $3.0$&\color{red}   $1.4$&   $0.2$&   setosa\tabularnewline
   $4.7$&   $3.2$&   $1.3$&   $0.2$&   setosa\tabularnewline
   $4.6$&   $3.1$&   $1.5$&   $0.2$&   setosa\tabularnewline
  $5.0$&   $3.6$&   $1.4$&   $0.2$&   setosa\tabularnewline
   $5.4$&   $3.9$&   $1.7$&   $0.4$&   setosa\tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

I am mainly looking for a solution that keeps the "purity" of red (i.e. when I reduce the intensity it's still red it just has white mixed in).

Comment: Are you looking for [Parametrize shading in table through TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42444/13304)?

Comment: The solution for red basically involves some function that implements `\cellcolor[rgb]{1,x,x}` where `x` is a real number in the interval `[0,1]`, however I'm not sophisticated enough to build it into a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specs in your question differ from those in your comment; I'm not sure what the syntax of your command should be. See if my code below answers your question. Otherwise, plese be more specific.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{calc}

\newcommand\cellRedBG[1]
  {\cellcolor{red!#1!white}}

\newcommand\cellRedFG[1]
    {\color{red!#1!black}}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{rrrrl}
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Sepal.Length}&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Sepal.Width}&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Petal.Length}&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Petal.Width}&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Species}
\tabularnewline
\hline

     $5.1$&   $3.5$&   $1.4$&   $0.2$&   setosa\tabularnewline
   $4.9$& \cellRedBG{20}   $3.0$&\cellRedFG{75}   $1.4$&   $0.2$&   setosa\tabularnewline
   $4.7$&   $3.2$&   $1.3$&   $0.2$&   setosa\tabularnewline
   $4.6$&   $3.1$&   $1.5$&   $0.2$&   setosa\tabularnewline
  $5.0$&   $3.6$&   $1.4$&   $0.2$&   setosa\tabularnewline
   $5.4$&   $3.9$&   $1.7$&   $0.4$&   setosa\tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```