# colour cells in a table according to the value

Tags: color, pgfplotstable

I have seen the following code in response to another similar question that works when the numbers in the table are between 0 and 100. How do I have to modify this code so that it works for numbers between 0 and 1 (or any arbitrary range?). My idea is that I need to modify the line:

```
\cellcolor{black!##1}
```

so that it somehow multiples this by 100, but I can't figure out how to do this.

Here is the full code that works for the numbers given (between 0 and 100) - I would like to do the same for number between 0 and 1. Thanks

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotstableset{
    color cells/.style={
        col sep=comma,
        string type,
        postproc cell content/.code={%
                \pgfkeysalso{@cell content=\rule{0cm}{2.4ex}\cellcolor{black!##1}\pgfmathtruncatemacro\number{##1}\ifnum\number>50\color{white}\fi##1}%
                },
        columns/x/.style={
            column name={},
            postproc cell content/.code={}
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}\caption{Correlation or something}
\centering
\pgfplotstabletypeset[color cells]{
x,a,b,c,d
a,90,10.5,0,0
b,0,80,10,10
c,0,0,95,5
d,0,10,5,85
}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Which one is the question you took this from?

Comment: It's this one   "Parametrize shading in table through TikZ". In any case I have copied the full code below:

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this. I have edited the question to include the full code. Thanks

Comment: That code seems to be the one from my answer to [Parametrize shading in table through TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42444/parametrize-shading-in-table-through-tikz). There's a much better implementation by Christian Feuersänger at [Drawing heatmaps using TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44868/drawing-heatmaps-using-tikz)

Comment: Thanks I have seen that code too.The problem with Christian's implementation is that it returns an error if the first column is comprised of string values rather than numbers.e.g.,  \pgfplotstabletypeset[     color cells={min=0,max=1},     col sep=comma,     /pgfplots/colormap={whiteblue}{rgb255(0cm)=(255,255,255); rgb255(1cm)=(0,0,188)}, ]
{
x,zs, pd, 
zs,0.605,0.954
pd,0.444,0.998
}                                                                    Also, is it be possible to implement the inverse shading of the text when the background becomes too dark that is in your code with Christian's?

Answer (score 2):

I've modified Christian's code a bit (basically destroyed visually and converted to a style) to limit the effective range of the macros defined. Otherwise `string type` columns also pick up the cell content setting directives. This allows to selectively enable the cell coloring.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable,colortbl}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\pgfplotstableset{
  /color cells/min/.initial=0,
  /color cells/max/.initial=1000,
  /color cells/textcolor/.initial=,
  color cells/.style={
    postproc cell content/.append code={%
          \pgfkeys{/color cells/.cd,#1}%
      \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@preprocessed cell content}\value%
      \ifx\value\empty%
      \else%
        \pgfmathfloatparsenumber{\value}\pgfmathfloattofixed{\pgfmathresult}%
        \let\value=\pgfmathresult%
        \pgfplotscolormapaccess%
            [\pgfkeysvalueof{/color cells/min}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/color cells/max}]%
            {\value}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/colormap name}}%
        \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}\typesetvalue%
        \pgfkeysgetvalue{/color cells/textcolor}\textcolorvalue%
        \toks0=\expandafter{\typesetvalue}%
        \edef\temp{\noexpand\pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{%
            \noexpand\cellcolor[rgb]{\pgfmathresult}%
            \noexpand\definecolor{mapped color}{rgb}{\pgfmathresult}%
            \ifx\textcolorvalue\empty\else\noexpand\color{\textcolorvalue}\fi%
            \the\toks0%
          }%
        }%
        \temp%
      \fi%
      }%
  }%
}%

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=comma,
/color cells/max=100,
/color cells/min=0,
/color cells/textcolor=white,
columns/a/.style={color cells},
columns/b/.style={color cells},
columns/c/.style={color cells},
columns/d/.style={color cells},
columns/x/.style={string type},
/pgfplots/colormap/blackwhite,
]{
x,a,b,c,d
a,90,10.5,0,0
b,0,80,10,10
c,0,0,95,5
d,0,10,5,85
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am using this code to color my cells according to a heatmap. Could someone give me a tip what I need to change in the above code if I additionally want to have the numbers printed in bold?