# How to make the equivalent of a seaborn heatmap?

Tags: tikz-pgf, python

I have been shifting to `tikz` to do my plots recently (from `matplotlib`), and I have to say I kind of like it a lot. It's very nice to have everything coherent, in font, code, colors and so on!

Unfortunately, I have not been able to reproduce yet the heatmap kind of plot. 
I have seen examples of course, but nothing that reached the quality of those made with the seaborn library in Python:

[image]

I would like to ask if someone would know how to approach this?

Best,
Pierre

Comment: You can do it so : https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44868/drawing-heatmaps-using-tikz

Answer (score 1):

`pgfplots` can do matrix plots.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[enlargelimits=false,colorbar,colormap/Purples]
    \addplot [matrix plot,point meta=explicit]
      coordinates {
        (0,0) [0] (1,0) [1] (2,0) [2]

        (0,1) [3] (1,1) [4] (2,1) [5]

        (0,2) [6] (1,2) [7] (2,2) [8]
      };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: very nice +1 for your answer.

Comment: @Sebastiano Pff, I just copied the manual.

Comment: Hello Henri, and thank you for your answer! I must apologize as I badly formulated the question... I had stopped working on it for some time, sorry. I've found an answer for the loading of the dataframe-like data here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42444/parametrize-shading-in-table-through-tikz

Thank you again, Pierre.