# Seaborn style plot of pandas dataframe

Tags: pgfplots

There is a [similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/405757/how-to-make-the-equivalent-of-a-seaborn-heatmap) like mine, but I am not satisfied with the answer, because the axis labels there are coordinates, while I am looking to also have the column and index labels written as text as in seaborn.

This is the output of from `seaborn` which I want to reproduce (never mind the colormap).

[image]

Here's the `python` code I use to generate an output for `pgfplots` to use.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
data = [[3, 10], [2, 15]] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['foo', 'bar'],index = ["foo2","bar2"]) 
sns.heatmap(df,annot=True)

def generate_file(df):
    with open("mwe.dat","w") as f:
        for i in range(len(df.index)):
            for j in range(len(df.columns)):
                f.write("{} {} {}\n".format(j,i,df.values[i][j]))
            f.write("\n")
generate_file(df)
```

This create `mwe.dat` with the following content:

```
0 0 3
1 0 10

0 1 2
1 1 15
```

And this is my `latex` mwe for my current solution, lacking the text labels and the values written in the middle:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[view={0}{90},
               colorbar,
]
    \addplot3[matrix plot,point meta=explicit] file {mwe.dat};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This currently outputs this:

[image]

So I have two questions:

- how to add text labels to axes, instead of coordinates?
- how to write the value in the middle of the cell?

Since I will be using `python` anyway to generate the original dataframes, it is okay if I need `python` to actually generate the entire `latex` code, but I would prefer a solution, where `python` only generates a data file containing all info needed for the plot (I want to avoid changing things by hand).

Comment: Would be nice if you could add `mwe.dat` to the question as well, so people don't have to run your Python code. Edit: and if I do run the Python code, the LaTeX example throws an error.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks, good idea, I updated the question.

Comment: @DJP there _was_ something off with the generated `mwe.dat`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you change the Python code to also print the column names and index values:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
data = [[3, 10], [2, 15]] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['foo', 'bar'],index = ["foo2","bar2"]) 
sns.heatmap(df,annot=True)

def generate_file(df):
    with open("mwe.dat","w") as f:
        f.write("x y z xl yl\n")
        for i,line in enumerate(df.values):
            for j,val in enumerate(line):
                f.write("{} {} {} {} {}\n".format(j,i,val, df.columns[j], df.index[j]))
            f.write("\n")
generate_file(df)
```

So `mwe.dat` becomes

```
x y z xl yl
0 0 3 foo foo2
1 0 10 bar bar2

0 1 2 foo foo2
1 1 15 bar bar2
```

Then you can set the tick locations and read the ticklabels from the file like in the code below. `x`/`yticklabels from table` seems to assume that the file has a header row, hence the addition of that.

`nodes near coords, nodes near coords align=center` can be used to place the values in the cells.

Note the use of `\addplot ... table` instead of `\addplot ... file`.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
     view={0}{90},
     colorbar,
     xtick=data,
     ytick=data,
     xticklabels from table={mwe.dat}{xl},
     yticklabels from table={mwe.dat}{yl},
     yticklabel style={rotate=90}
]
    \addplot3[matrix plot, nodes near coords, nodes near coords align=center] table {mwe.dat};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I removed `point meta=explicit` because that caused an error.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. ok, thanks, I'll wait until you conclude this to accept the answer, to have it all rounded up, but this is already pretty cool, thanks

Comment: @fbence I think `x`/`yticklabels from table` assumes the presence of a header row, so the first row was basically skipped, and the second and third row was used. That explains why the order is reversed, as the file had `foo, bar, foo, bar`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=20pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots, filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\begin{document}
\begin{filecontents*}{mwe.dat}
0 0 3
1 0 10

0 1 2
1 1 15
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[view={0}{90}, colorbar,hide axis,nodes near coords = {\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta}]
    \addplot [matrix plot*,point meta=explicit] file {mwe.dat};
    \node[] at (axis cs: -0.010,-.65) {foo};
    \node[] at (axis cs: 0.980,-.65) {bar};
    \node[rotate=90] at (axis cs: -0.59,.01) {bar2};
    \node[rotate=90] at (axis cs: -0.590,1.0) {foo2};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output from Gummi is:
[image]

With respect to your question "how to add text labels to axes, instead of coordinates?" I did `hide axis` in setting the axis. Then I added nodes with the labels you wanted and positioned them and rotated them where you wanted. As for "how to write the value in the middle of the cell?", I added `nodes near coords = {\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta}` in setting up the axis. **I'm wondering about the data file matching up with your picture, though, as the numbers are in the wrong row. The colors are in different rows as well**.