# Equivalent to seaborn's heatmap in tikz from csv?

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices, plot

Is it possible to make a neat equivalent to `python`'s heatmaps obtained with `seaborn` from a csv file?

Example file data.csv:

```
,a,b,c,d
A, 50,-300,-200,-100
B, -20,0,100,200
C, 5,300,40,800
D, 3,30,50,70
```

Previously answered question proposes the long home made approach, that is hardly customizable by the neophyte: 
[Drawing heatmaps using TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44868/drawing-heatmaps-using-tikz)

Another proposes to use the latex tables:
[Parametrize shading in table through TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42444/parametrize-shading-in-table-through-tikz)

But either seem to be little scalable (for instance my data file could have 1000 rows), hardly customizable (I will want to put custom yticks every 10 row) and less maintainable...

Original python code:

```
ax = sns.heatmap(df, xticklabels=xticks, square=True, linewidth=.5)
ax.set_xticks(np.linspace(0, 1, 11)*ax.get_xlim()[1])
```