# X-Y plot with variable diameter points

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

I want to draw an X-Y plot where each point has a kind of "third dimensional" value that I want to represent using different points "size" (points are circles with different diameters).

I already successfully used the TikZ plotting capabilities, and want to ask, can I achieve easily the effect previously described? What are the other libraries I can/should use for this purpose?

I am not looking for a detailed solution, but for the right direction to start with.

Comment: Note that this is commonly called a "bubble chart".

Comment: Possibly related: (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20496/drawing-different-tikz-shapes-parameterized-by-data-from-a-file/20501#20501)