# Points/Circles in graph with TikZ based on table within .tex-file?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

Suppose I have a table such as

```
\documentclass[
a4paper
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{
tgheros,
booktabs
}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{lrrrrr}
\toprule
Unit & Thing & Word & More & Things & Letter\\
\toprule
A & 4 & 15 & 10 & 0.4 & 1.5 \\
\midrule
B & 2 & 12 & 7 & 0.29 & 1.71 \\
\midrule
C & 6 & 3\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        stuff.
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Is it possible to feed the last 2 columns as x- and y-values as (data) points to a TikZ figure in the same document? Or maybe even another .tex-file?

In the end, what I would like to do within the `tikzpicture`-environment would be something like

```
\node (A) at (x-value-from-above,y-value-from-above) {};
\filldraw (A) circle (0.1cm) node[stylething] {Something};
```

And all in all, is it maybe automate the procedure? I think what it could lead to would be a giant macro which I could not program anyway. How does anyone else do it? Is it always the pgfplots-table method?

Comment: That sounds pretty much like a scatterplot. Is that what you're trying to achieve, or do you have something else in mind?

Comment: Well, if you are referring to [this kind of scatterplot](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/scatterplot/), not quite. I amended my op, I hoped I succeeded to clarify the issue?

Comment: Do you want to keep those tabular row format with ampersands and \\ ? I mean do you need to convert a table data or can it be a foreach macro? `pgfplotstable` would be quite easier of course.

Comment: “Even another file” would probably easier to feed as you don’t have `\toprule` and stuff there, although `pgfplotstable` could be used to both display the table as well as plot something from it. Besides the `x` and `y` value what else from the table should be in the plot. What is `stylething`, what is `Something`? Could you make a complete TikZ picture including the actual output from the table? Mind you, the last row is missing some column. By the way, in your example, you could just say `\node[stylething, circle, draw] at (<x>,<y>) {Something};` where the node automatically expands.

Comment: Do you perhaps mean something like [Drawing different tikz shapes parameterized by data from a file](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20496/drawing-different-tikz-shapes-parameterized-by-data-from-a-file)?

Comment: @percusse Well I am preparing the tables in Calc/Excel and exporting them via the 2 relevant tools... but the thing is, I favor the amount of little option with TikZ as I see pgfplots as a macro package on top of that and ran into just too many desperate situation 1-2 years back. But I guess I could use both packages in a doc.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Those were, of course, arbitrary style options or sth. similar. Also, not always is data complete. I probably could have indicated that as the 4th and 5th columns were ratios of the 1st&3rd and 2nd&3rd, this row is incomplete. About the your code suggestion, the node naming was omitted.

Comment: @Jake Actually your comment turned out to be the one that helped me the most. Thanks.